# Spring servlet for serving static content?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I'm wondering what's the Spring way of serving static files. It should support:

- Written in a Springy way!
- Simple and reliable
- **Support for resuming downloads** (eg. Range request header, and Accept-Ranges, ETag and Last-Modified response headers).
- **Support for client-side caching** (eg. If-None-Match and If-Modified-Since request headers, and HEAD requests for ETag, Last-Modified, and Expires response headers
- **Support for GZIP compression** (eg. Accept-Encoding: gzip header)

Something like the following, but using the idioms of Spring 3...

- [BalusC FileServlet supporting resume and caching and GZIP](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html)
- [Servlet for serving static content (question on SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `@Controller` with `@RequestMapping("/static/{resourceName}` and use the same logic as in BalusC's Servlet

As for gzip - use Tomcat's or Apache's configuration options.