# Download a file from Servlet using Ajax

Tags: ajax, servlets, download, save-as

I have created a zip file in my servlet. Now I would like to trigger that servlet using Ajax and prompt the download dialog to the user. I can trigger the servlet, but I don't know how to get the save dialog. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

You can't "download a file using AJAX". AJAX is about downloading data from a server for JavaScript to process.

To let the user download the file either use a simple link to the file/servlet, or if you really, really need to use JavaScript, then assign the URL to `document.location.href`.

Also you need to make sure that the server (or in this case the servlet) sends the appropriate MIME type, in case of a ZIP file most likely `application/zip`.

Comment: Problem is On a link i have to download a file , i dont want to navigate to another page , I have tried out by calling a servlet by forms , that works fine but now I need to download the file on the click of the link .

Comment: Huh? Using a normal link `<a href="/path/to/file">Download</a>` **will** "download the file on the click of the link".

Answer (score 9):

You can't use Ajax for this. You basically want to let the enduser save the file content to the local disk file system, not to assign the file content to a JavaScript variable where it can't do anything with it. JavaScript has for obvious security reasons no facilities to programmatically trigger the *Save As* dialog whereby the file content is provided from an arbitrary JavaScript variable.

Just have a plain vanilla link point to the servlet URL and let the servlet set the HTTP `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment`. It's specifically this header which will force the browser to pop a *Save As* dialog. The underlying page will stay same and not get refreshed or so, achieving the same experience as with Ajax.

Basically:

```
<a href="fileservlet/somefilename.zip">download file</a>
```

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // ...

    response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(fileName));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

    // ...
}
```

That could also be done in JavaScript as below without firing a whole Ajax call:

```
window.location = "fileservlet/somefilename.zip";
```

Alternatively, if you're actually using POST for this, then use a (hidden) synchronous POST form referring the servlet's URL and let JavaScript perform a `form.submit()` on it.

#### See also:

- [Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java)
- [Abstract template for a static resource servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content/29991447#29991447)

Answer (score 0):

```
function down() {

    var url = "/Jad";
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //alert("xmlhttp.status" + xmlhttp.status);
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

        }

    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();


    var elemIF = document.createElement("iframe");
    elemIF.src = url;
    elemIF.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(elemIF);
}
```

Comment: The ajax part is completely unnecessary. It won't work anyway (as answered by others). Just the last four lines are sufficient. Much eaiser is to use `window.location = url;` if you can guarantee that the server side returns `Content-Disposition:attachment`.