# Web Api download file using jQuery Ajax but not with fileName

Tags: filenames, export-to-excel, asp.net-apicontroller

according to the link
[Web Api won't download file using jQuery Ajax and Basic Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084231/web-api-wont-download-file-using-jquery-ajax-and-basic-auth/23515554#23515554)
whitch solution have helped me a lot ,
i wanted to ask question:
why the confirmation to user about opening/saving file doesn't show its name(export_gui) but the controller name(in IE: downloadget; in chrome: "הורד 6" without extension xls)?

thanks

Comment: i found the solution: add this row to DownloadController Get method:result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution: add this row to DownloadController Get method:result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;