# JavaScript blob filename without link

Tags: javascript, html, download, blob, html5-filesystem

How do you set the name of a blob file in JavaScript when force downloading it through `window.location`?

```
function newFile(data) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    var blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"});
    var url  = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.location.assign(url);
}
```

Running the above code downloads a file instantly without a page refresh that looks like:

**bfefe410-8d9c-4883-86c5-d76c50a24a1d**

I want to set the filename as ***my-download.json*** instead.

Answer (score 489, accepted):

The only way I'm aware of is the trick used by [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/):

1. Create a hidden `<a>` tag.
2. Set its `href` attribute to the blob's URL.
3. Set its [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) attribute to the filename.
4. Click on the `<a>` tag.

Here is a simplified example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cW7W5/)):

```
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());

var data = { x: 42, s: "hello, world", d: new Date() },
    fileName = "my-download.json";

saveData(data, fileName);
```

I wrote this example just to illustrate the idea, in production code use FileSaver.js instead.

**Notes**

- Older browsers don't support the "download" attribute, since it's part of HTML5.
- Some file formats are considered insecure by the browser and the download fails. Saving JSON files with txt extension works for me.

Comment: Oddly it seems to be failing when I copy and paste this into CodePen. Although your code seems legit and good http://codepen.io/ashblue/pen/jEhmH

Comment: Your codepen code works for me in Chrome. The json file is saved into the download folder of Chrome.

Comment: @AshBlue The "download" attribute needs HTML5. My code is just an example, you could also try the FileSaver.js demo page: http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Comment: I'm getting "Failed - No file" on Chrome Windows ver 30. Is it maybe a Windows exclusive bug?

Comment: The download works for me on a Windows 7 PC, but I got the "Failed - No file" message on Windows XP. Interestingly, The FileSaver.js demo page is able to download files to XP.

Comment: I've found a workaround: if I change the extension to txt, then the download works.

Comment: Interestingly, if you repeatedly try to download a txt this way (by pressing the Run button on jsfiddle.net again and again), the download sometimes fails.

Comment: i allready have an <a id="saveToJson">save as JSON</a> link. i do the Blob creatin logic in the $("#saveToJson") callback function but the problem is i can't do this.click() unless the function is gonna run itself over and over again.
ps: i don't like to create those hidden workaround filds so i wanted to set the attributes of my element when it's clicked.

Comment: @philx_x Since you already have an <a> tag, and create the Blob in its click handler, you don't have to call `.click()` yourself, because it will cause infinite recursion.

Comment: @xheyhenry FileSaver.js should work in IE10+: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/#supported-browsers There is a workaround for IE<10: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/#ie--10

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this solution will not work for files with sizes greater than a particular threshold. e.g-> 2 MB for chrome. This size varies from browser to browser.

Comment: This does not work for me because I need to open the file in a new tab. I have to show a PDF in Chrome, but I need to show a user friendly name in the URL toolbar, and if the user wants to download through the download icon, I have to put the same user friendly name in the file.

Comment: Can I do this kind of thing without using <a> tag and window. Window is not available in all browsers and I do not want to create an <a> tag in my angular app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52273870/2730032 works for me without needing the <a> trick used here and in the other answers. Is there a reason why it's not more upvoted and that this is still the top answer ?

Comment: @Ixio Isn't `msSaveOrOpenBlob` Internet Explorer specific?

Comment: @kol probably but I used the technique for other browsers: window.location = URL.createObjectURL(new File(...)) and it works fine for me on Firefox (I don't know about other browsers).

Comment: For some reason, this fails for me when using Babel with Webpack, because the body element is not available yet, even if the code is only called after the document is loaded or not called at all. When using the untranspiled ES6 module source code, it works fine. I changed it to a normal function and declaring a reused a element outside of the function.

Comment: Just to add, you don't need to actually mount the a tag to the body in order for this to work (tried just now in Chrome)

Comment: How can I make works for the video tag with blob data.[How to set the download file extension for blob data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71686536/6521116)

Comment: Why is saveData declared as an IIFE?

Comment: weirdly enough, this adds auto file extensions when the filename is without one... I had some logfile called `logfile` and chrome made it `logfile.xml` without any indication from  my side (it's not even an xml file)

Comment: Wow. `a.click()` just sopped working for my users in Chrome / downloads the ugly random filename. Looking at the FileSaver.js source, they've had [a replacement for click()](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blame/master/src/FileSaver.js#L58-L67) since 2018: e.g. `a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))`

Answer (score 71):

I just wanted to expand on the accepted answer with support for Internet Explorer (most modern versions, anyways), and to tidy up the code using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    saveFile("Example.txt", "data:attachment/text", "Hello, world.");
});

function saveFile (name, type, data) {
    if (data !== null && navigator.msSaveBlob)
        return navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([data], { type: type }), name);
    var a = $("<a style='display: none;'/>");
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {type: type}));
    a.attr("href", url);
    a.attr("download", name);
    $("body").append(a);
    a[0].click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    a.remove();
}
```

[Here is an example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efu5vhaf/). **Godspeed**.

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Comment: I used the accepted solution but it didn't work at firefox! I still don't know why. Your solution worked in firefox. Thanks.

Answer (score 57):

Same principle as the solutions above. But I had issues with Firefox 52.0 (32 bit) where large files (>40 MBytes) are truncated at random positions. Re-scheduling the call of revokeObjectUrl() fixes this issue.

```
function saveFile(blob, filename) {
  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }, 0)
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/KimNyholm/p48nt3h7/)

Comment: I found that this setTimeout() hack fixes MS Edge, where the file would not download at all. However, only the call to revokeObjectURL() needs to be delayed.

Comment: I found that the "if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)" is what did the trick for me

Answer (score 38):

Late, but since I had the same problem I add my solution:

```js
function newFile(data, fileName)
{
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    //IE11 support
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        let blob = new Blob([json], {type: "application/json"});
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {// other browsers
        let file = new File([json], fileName, {type: "application/json"});
        let exportUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        window.location.assign(exportUrl);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(exportUrl);
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="newFile({a:1}, 'file.json')">Export data to JSON</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @ben. This is working fine. No dom elements, nothing like to trigger like click event. It just works awesome with proper extension. But the given file name is not considered, downloading "<object_url_id>.csv" instead of "<myfileName>.csv"

Comment: Calling `revokeObjectURL` after `location.assign` works fine in Firefox, but breaks the download on Chrome.

Comment: Note that "Edge does not support the File constructor." Ref. https://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi

Comment: This should be the correct answer. No point in creating useless objects in the DOM tree

Comment: Now it does, since Jan '20

Comment: As @RamBabuS says, this is not keeping `fileName`, but besides that works perfectly for me

Comment: There is no need to call revokeObjectURL, the URL will automatically be revoked when the creating document (the page you were on) is closed. Which is also why you must use a new tab to view the file (at least in chrome).

Comment: Can I download a blob video with this function?

Comment: The filename property works in firefox, but not in chrome... anyone a solution for chrome?

Comment: The file name is not working in Chrome, so don't waste your time

Comment: Great solution, still filename not working in Chrome (or Safari)...Any news on this for these browsers?!

Comment: That's the way! Good answer.

Answer (score 9):

This is my solution. From my point of view, you can not bypass the `<a>`.

```js
function export2json() {
  const data = {
    a: '111',
    b: '222',
    c: '333'
  };
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)], {
      type: "application/json"
    })
  );
  a.setAttribute("download", "data.json");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="export2json()">Export data to json file</button>
```

Comment: You are leaking a blob url here though.

Answer (score 7):

```
saveFileOnUserDevice = function(file){ // content: blob, name: string
        if(navigator.msSaveBlob){ // For ie and Edge
            return navigator.msSaveBlob(file.content, file.name);
        }
        else{
            let link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file.content);
            link.download = file.name;
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window}));
            link.remove();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there any way to open in it a new window?

Comment: I think you can call `link.click()` instead of dispatching a mouse event.

Answer (score 5):

**Working example** of a download button, to save a cat photo from an url as "cat.jpg":

HTML:

```
<button onclick="downloadUrl('https://i.imgur.com/AD3MbBi.jpg', 'cat.jpg')">Download</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function downloadUrl(url, filename) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      const blob = this.response;
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      a.href = blobUrl;
      a.download = filename;
      a.click();
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
        document.body.removeChild(a);
      }, 0);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: well done, thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

window.location.assign did not work for me. it downloads fine but downloads without an extension for a CSV file on Windows platform. The following worked for me.

```
    var blob = new Blob([csvString], { type: 'text/csv' });
    //window.location.assign(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    var link = window.document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // Construct filename dynamically and set to link.download
    link.download = link.href.split('/').pop() + '.' + extension; 
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use File instead

**[File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)** support name, moreover it's created on top of Blob and can be used when you want to obtain a Blob object for a file on the user's file system.

`var file = new File([json], name, {type: "octet/stream"});`

Answer (score -3):

this is a good easy solution for it.

```
function downloadBloob(blob,FileName) {
    var link = document.createElement("a"); // Or maybe get it from the current document
    link.href = blob;
    link.download = FileName;
    link.click();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This didn't work for me. You have to add "link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);" instead of "link.href = blob". Otherwise, it will give you an URL like this "http://localhost:3001/[object%20 Blob]" and the file will be empty and it will not work.