# Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to save my HTML file in Chrome when the user presses `ctrl + s` keys but Chrome is crashed.

(I want to download just the source code of my HTML file)

I read that it happens because my file is bigger than 1.99M..

**In the first attempt (before I knew about the crashing in Chrome):**

```
function download(filename, text) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
    pom.click();
}

download('test.html', "<html>" + document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML + "</html>");
```

**The second attempt, after I read about the crashing, I used `blob`:**

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var bb = new BlobBuilder();
    bb.append(ab);
    return bb.getBlob(mimeString);
}

function download(dataURI) {
    var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURI);
    var url  = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.location.assign(url);
}

download("<html>" + document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML + "</html>")
```

Here I got the error: `Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`

I don't know, but I read that I need to encode my string to base64: [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

There is an answer of 148 votes. I paste it in my code and don't know how to continue.

Where should I call it and how? Can I put a name on my saved file?

I think that I need to do something like:

```
download(_utf8_decode("<html>" + document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML + "</html>"))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an html file..
there are inputs that can be inserted dynamically.. (and the user can write text in these inputs).. after he finishes writing the text, I want to save the page with his changes, in order to let him continue in the point he left..

Comment: Why don't you save only the inputs and then embed them on the next page?

Comment: I didn't understand you.. the user will be able to continue in the point he left? if he can, suggest me please..

assuming I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/

and I add 3 inputs.. how can I let the user close the file and then continue in the point he left (there are 3 more inputs)..

(assuming I have only html file with big data.. 4 mb)

Comment: Try to find (in your code) the redirection path, and put your eyes on it, maybe in your function download()... searching a litle on your code, look at URI definition! that`s happend on both environment? or only on production when you are trying to deploy?

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, and should instead be posted as a comment on the original question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`BlobBuilder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder) is obsolete, use [`Blob` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) instead:

```
URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([/*whatever content*/] , {type:'text/plain'}));
```

This returns a blob URL which you can then use in an anchor's `href`. You can also modify an anchor's `download` attribute to manipulate the file name:

```
<a href="/*assign url here*/" id="link" download="whatever.txt">download me</a>
```

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/7NqKb/). If I recall correctly, there are arbitrary restrictions on trusted non-user initiated downloads; thus we'll stick with a link clicking which is seen as sufficiently user-initiated :)

**Update:** it's actually pretty trivial to save current document's html! Whenever our interactive link is clicked, we'll update its `href` with a relevant blob. After executing the click-bound event, that's the download URL that will be navigated to!

```
$('#link').on('click', function(e){
  this.href = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([document.documentElement.outerHTML] , {type:'text/html'})
  );
});
```

[Fiddled again](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/7NqKb/1/).

Comment: thank you for your comment.. unfortunately, it saves me the html before my changes.. (it doesn't save the text I entered).. I think you are so closer.. I didn't succeed to save the html before I saw your jsfiddle.. please help me again :)

for example: http://jsfiddle.net/7NqKb/3/

please enter a text and press `download me`

Comment: I tried: document.documentElement.outerHTML, document.documentElement.innerHTML, document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML.. but it doesn't remember the added inputs :/

Comment: @AlonShmiel: remember that when changing input text etc. you're not modifying html, you're modifying the DOM! You'll have to serialize DOM back into html/xhtml as `innerHTML`/`outerHTML` don't reflect mutations.

Comment: @AlonShmiel - I think you can run something like `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelector('input'), function (e) { e.setAttribute('value', e.value); });` (and similar for `textarea` and `select`) before updating the download link.

Answer (score 11):

> Here I got the error: `Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`

Because you didn't pass a base64-encoded string. Look at your functions: both `download` and `dataURItoBlob` do expect a *data URI* for some reason; you however are passing a plain html markup string to `download` in your example.

Not only is HTML invalid as base64, you are calling `.split(',')[1]` on it which will yield `undefined` - and `"undefined"` is not a valid base64-encoded string either.

> I don't know, but I read that I need to encode my string to base64

That doesn't make much sense to me. You want to encode it somehow, only to decode it then?

> What should I call and how?

Change the interface of your `download` function back to where it received the `filename` and `text` arguments.

Notice that the [`BlobBuilder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder) does not only support appending whole strings (so you don't need to create those `ArrayBuffer` things), but also is deprecated in favor of the [`Blob` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

> Can I put a name on my saved file?

Yes. Don't use the [`Blob`](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#blob) constructor, but the [`File`](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#file) constructor.

```
function download(filename, text) {
    try {
        var file = new File([text], filename, {type:"text/plain"});
    } catch(e) {
        // when File constructor is not supported
        file = new Blob([text], {type:"text/plain"});
    }
    var url  = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    …
}

download('test.html', "<html>" + document.documentElement.innerHTML + "</html>");
```

See [JavaScript blob filename without link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19327749/1048572) on what to do with that object url, just setting the current location to it doesn't work.

Comment: thank you..
I got: Failed to construct 'File': Illegal constructor 

I'm checking it..

Comment: I didn't test the code, sorry. Probably the `File` constructor is too new to be supported in (your) browser, [MDN doesn't mention it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) which was why I linked the spec draft. Try using the `Blob` constructor (without filename however), which [is supported in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: it opened a page that his title is: `Blob:8db3e422-8597-4beb-....`, the content is all of my html source, and  there is a message 'script is not responding'.. it wrote me it in the chrome and firefox..

Answer (score 7):

you don't need to pass the entire encoded string to atob method, you need to split the encoded string and pass the required string to atob method

```js
const token= "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJob3NzYW0iLCJUb2tlblR5cGUiOiJCZWFyZXIiLCJyb2xlIjoiQURNSU4iLCJpc0FkbWluIjp0cnVlLCJFbXBsb3llZUlkIjoxLCJleHAiOjE2MTI5NDA2NTksImlhdCI6MTYxMjkzNzA1OX0.8f0EeYbGyxt9hjggYW1vR5hMHFVXL4ZvjTA6XgCCAUnvacx_Dhbu1OGh8v5fCsCxXQnJ8iAIZDIgOAIeE55LUw"
console.log(atob(token.split(".")[1]));
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was going nuts since there wasn't any issues with the string to be decoded, since I could successfully decode it on online tools. 
Until I found out that you first have to `decodeURIComponent` what you are decoding, like so:

```
atob(decodeURIComponent(dataToBeDecoded));
```

Comment: This solved it for me too :)

Answer (score 2):

here's an updated fiddle where the user's input is saved in local storage automatically.  each time the fiddle is re-run or the page is refreshed the previous state is restored.  **this way you do not need to prompt users to save, it just saves on it's own.**

http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/9397/

stack overflow requires I include some code with a jsFiddle link so please ignore snippet:

```
localStorage.setItem(...)
```

Comment: I don't see how this answer the question. The OP does want to *download* the current html as a *file*, not store something in local storage?

Comment: But it might be an alternative for what the OP is trying to accomplish as per the comments

Comment: right- I think my answer is appropriate when you take this comment into consideration: _I want to save the page with his changes, in order to let him continue in the point he left._

Comment: thank you for your comment.. I have a lot of inputs so your solution seems to me too hard.. but if I didn't find another solution, your solution will help me.. thank you for your comment!! :]

Comment: I'm afraid my solution is the only one that's going to solve your issue:  _saving the state of the inputs_

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and what the fix I found was that in messaging.usePublicVapidKey('PAIR KEY')
i was using the server key and it needs the "pair key". You could find that info in https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging/

So the value of that function is the pair key in the console, i was confused and put the server key ‍♂️ and that create the bug of Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window':.

Answer (score 0):

#### Unit testing

In my case I simply forgot to pass `btoa(mockData)` instead of passing the plain `mockData` to the function I was trying to test.

Answer (score -1):

Use this function Convert.ToBase64String()

```bash
await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFromByteArray", 
Convert.ToBase64String(baosDest.ToArray()),FinalPdf, "application/pdf");
```