# error on crypting personal data atob

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, crypt

So, this is issue:

```
Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.
```

This happens when I trying to encode data when session starts, so in auth.js I have this:

```
function Auth($rootScope, $window, $state, Restangular, userInfo) {
  var token = $window.localStorage.token;
  if (token) {
    var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));
    $rootScope.currentUser = payload.user;
  }

  return {
    signup: function(userinfo, callback) {
      var cb = callback || angular.noop;
      Restangular.all('auth/signup').post(userinfo).then(function() {
        return cb();
      }, function(response) {
        return cb(response.data);
      });
    },
    login: function(user, callback) {
      var cb = callback || angular.noop;
      Restangular.all('auth/login').post(user).then(function(data) {
        $window.localStorage.token = data.token;
        var payload = JSON.parse($window.atob(data.token.split('.')[1]));
        $rootScope.currentUser = payload.user;
        return cb();
      }, function(response) {
        delete $window.localStorage.token;
        return cb(response.data);
      });
    }
```

On other machines it works fine, but I have this problem. So, can you tell me from what can i start to find solution? 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript#246813) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578530/failed-to-execute-atob-on-window) already saw. There is no idea in my head

Answer (score 1):

Think we're looking at the same Tut.
Instead of:

```
$window.atob(data.token.split('.')[1])
```

Try this:

```
window.atob(window.localStorage['YOUR-ELEMENT'].split('.')[1])
```

"$window" is not defined.