# Error:Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

Tags: html, angularjs

*This is my Javascript code*

```
function upload(){
var byteCharacters = atob($scope.image1.compressed.dataURL.replace(/^data:image\(png|jpg);base64,/,''));
var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
         for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
          byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
         }
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
 var blob = new Blob([ byteArray ], {
     type : undefined
   });
```

*This is my HTML*

```
<div class="form-group text-16px" style="margin-top: 20px !important;">
    <label>Choose Material Photo : </label>
    <div>
    <input id="materialImage" type="file" accept="image/*" image="image1" resize-max-height="800" resize-max-width="800" resize-quality="0.7" resize-type="image/jpg" file-model="file" name="materialImage" onChange="checkFile()" ng-image-compress/>
    <div id="choose-image-compresser">
      <div image="image1" result-image="myCompressedImage"></div>
      </div>
    <img ng-src="{{image1.compressed.dataURL}}" />
        <span id="image-size-error" style="color:red;" hidden=""><small>Image size is too large</small></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I am getting error**

> Error: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded
>   is not correctly encoded

Comment: in my controller var byteCharacters = atob($scope.image1.compressed.dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/,''));
                                var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);

Comment: my html code is <input id="materialImage" type="file" accept="image/*" image="image1" resize-max-height="800" resize-max-width="800" resize-quality="0.7" resize-type="image/jpg" file-model="file" name="materialImage" onChange="checkFile()" ng-image-compress/>
 <div id="choose-image-compresser">
   <div image="image1" result-image="myCompressedImage"></div>
   </div>

Comment: Possible duplicate question, Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578530/failed-to-execute-atob-on-window

Comment: please check my code i'm using image compression in my controller

Comment: @ARJUN Please check my code and understand my problem. please don't give me a negative marking. Please check my code. i spent 4 days. and i'm not able to find out proper solutions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got my problem. It should be helpful for another user for save the image and compress the image using javascript(AnguarJs).

**I am flowing this link to compress the image** [Github](https://github.com/oukan/angular-image-compress)

https://github.com/oukan/angular-image-compress

```
var imageData = $scope.image1.compressed.dataURL.toString();
var byteCharacters = atob(imageData.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg|jpg);base64,/, ''));
var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
  byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
}

var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
var blob = new Blob([ byteArray ], {
   type : undefined
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked. I was getting this error while taking photos using my laptop camera.  changing the replace string worked for me.

Comment: @JagdishChopde: Welcome  >(* _*)< , Glad to help

Answer (score 2):

After checking out your code it seems like you have characters which are not probably supported.
[Check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxZFY.jpg) 
If that doesn't work make sure the name of the file you are trying to upload is encoded to what your database or settings support.

Here is the code without those characters:

```
var byteCharacters = atob($scope.image1.compressed.dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/,'')); var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
```

Comment: var byteCharacters = atob($scope.image1.compressed.dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/,''));
                                var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
                                for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
                                    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters
                                            .charCodeAt(i);
                       }
                                var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers); {
                                    type : undefined
                                });

Comment: @VedPrakash You seem to have an encoding problem. After I copied your I noticed that part of it is not UTF-8 Encoded. That might be the reason.
This part of it to be precise " /^data:image\/‌​(png|jpg);base64,/,'‌​' "
I deleted those invisible characters so it should be good.
This is the  new code: `var byteCharacters = atob($scope.image1.compressed.dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/,'')); `

Comment: #Earl :- Code is not working. Still i have same problem

Comment: var byteCharacters = atob(imageData.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, ''));  ***i added jpeg any my issue is fix.