# Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

Tags: javascript, blob

I'm trying to Convert data URI to image data but I faced this error:

> Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not
>     correctly encoded

the function:

```
function dataURLtoBlob(dataurl) {
  var arr = dataurl.split(',');
  var mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
  var bstr = window.atob(arr[1]);
  var n = bstr.length;
  var u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

  while (n--) {
    u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
  }
  return new Blob([u8arr], {
    type: mime
  });
}
```

dataurl is:

> src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAgAElEQVR4Xmy9edRl6VXe95z5nHvuvd9Uc5W6q9WSWiOSGISEmCQmx2ZKCAtjsryygv9JVsY/SGwSRw54GezYBiHANEkV7WeKQBWriul64VufPLj2vMCbSUTqQU5OAPx2lIl+S0qZWAskN2jLhaZ5ioaZRZBgMbG1AL…

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Probably the one in the question's title?

Comment: The compiler is telling you the problem. Your `src` string is not correctly encoded. Therefore, you cannot decode it.

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus - edited question

Comment: but i'm sure it correctly encoded @adam-beck , do you know exactlly what's the problem ?

Comment: How are you so sure?

Comment: from this http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter @ adam-beck

Comment: i tried full encoded string it generate the image

Comment: I am facing the same issue, Any solution to this???

Comment: Did you check out this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490904/errorfailed-to-execute-atob-on-window-the-string-to-be-decoded-is-not-corr