# Failed to decode base64 in javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, decoder

I receive an `id_token` as part of my current href. It is encoded in base64. I try to decode it using `atob(extractedIdToken)`, but get the following error:

> Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

When I copy and paste the extracted `id_token` in my code and go to an online decoding site, it decodes correctly. Do you have suggestion?

Comment: Can you include the string and reproduce error message at stacksnippets at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: See SO:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578530/failed-to-execute-atob-on-window

Comment: I have solved my issue by writing the decoder in the backend and call it front end. See my answer at the end.

Comment: Then, the issue was also resolved in the front end. Just check my second answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers. I ended up moving the Base64 decoding process to the Java backend using the java package: java.util.Base64.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this to decode and encode in Base64, try it

```
var Base64 = {
    _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
    encode: function (e) {
        var t = "";
        var n, r, i, s, o, u, a;
        var f = 0;
        e = Base64._utf8_encode(e);
        while (f < e.length) {
            n = e.charCodeAt(f++);
            r = e.charCodeAt(f++);
            i = e.charCodeAt(f++);
            s = n >> 2;
            o = (n & 3) << 4 | r >> 4;
            u = (r & 15) << 2 | i >> 6;
            a = i & 63;
            if (isNaN(r)) {
                u = a = 64
            } else if (isNaN(i)) {
                a = 64
            }
            t = t + this._keyStr.charAt(s) + this._keyStr.charAt(o) + this._keyStr.charAt(u) + this._keyStr.charAt(a)
        }
        return t
    },
    decode: function (e) {
        var t = "";
        var n, r, i;
        var s, o, u, a;
        var f = 0;
        e = e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g, "");
        while (f < e.length) {
            s = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            o = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            u = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            a = this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));
            n = s << 2 | o >> 4;
            r = (o & 15) << 4 | u >> 2;
            i = (u & 3) << 6 | a;
            t = t + String.fromCharCode(n);
            if (u != 64) {
                t = t + String.fromCharCode(r)
            }
            if (a != 64) {
                t = t + String.fromCharCode(i)
            }
        }
        t = Base64._utf8_decode(t);
        return t
    },
    _utf8_encode: function (e) {
        e = e.replace(/rn/g, "n");
        var t = "";
        for (var n = 0; n < e.length; n++) {
            var r = e.charCodeAt(n);
            if (r < 128) {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r)
            } else if (r > 127 && r < 2048) {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 | 192);
                t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128)
            } else {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 12 | 224);
                t += String.fromCharCode(r >> 6 & 63 | 128);
                t += String.fromCharCode(r & 63 | 128)
            }
        }
        return t
    },
    _utf8_decode: function (e) {
        var t = "";
        var n = 0;
        var r = c1 = c2 = 0;
        while (n < e.length) {
            r = e.charCodeAt(n);
            if (r < 128) {
                t += String.fromCharCode(r);
                n++
            } else if (r > 191 && r < 224) {
                c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1);
                t += String.fromCharCode((r & 31) << 6 | c2 & 63);
                n += 2
            } else {
                c2 = e.charCodeAt(n + 1);
                c3 = e.charCodeAt(n + 2);
                t += String.fromCharCode((r & 15) << 12 | (c2 & 63) << 6 | c3 & 63);
                n += 3
            }
        }
        return t
    }
};
```

Comment: Please stop adding it back in, that is not JSON, it's a JavaScript Object.

Comment: How does the code at Answer resolve Question? Is the code at Answer copy/pasted from an existing Answer at SO?

Comment: I apologize, this function only get string to return string, Your problem seems to use blob. Maybe here has the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490904/errorfailed-to-execute-atob-on-window-the-string-to-be-decoded-is-not-corr

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that the encoded string should have been treated as segments. Just separate the code with the separator "." or whatever your case is. Then, decode only the different parts separately. This resolved my issue and I was able to decode using window.atob(). Hope this helps.