# Decoding a JWT token on frontend with atob gives me failed to execute 'atob' on 'window' error

Tags: javascript, typescript

On frontend I am checking if my JWT is expired.

Function is:

```
tokenExpired(token: string) {
    const expiry = JSON.parse(window.atob(token.split('.')[1])).exp;
    return Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) >= expiry;
  }
```

And then using this function like:

```
 if (!this.tokenExpired(this.jwtToken || '')) {
      this.getAccountData().subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.accout = data;
          this.isLoggedIn();
        },
        (err) => {
          this.isLoggedIn$.next(2);
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.isLoggedIn$.next(2);
    }
```

When I build my application it gives me an error in console.log:
**Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.**

What are some alternatives to use instead of atob or window.atob?

Thank you!

**SOLVED --> solution:**

```
 tokenExpired(token: string) {
    if (token !== '') {
      const expiry = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1])).exp;
      return Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) >= expiry;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Is this solution a good practice? It doesn't give me an error

Comment: ~~Are you in the GUI thread of a browser? Try without the `window.` part.~~ Also, `Date.now()` (instead of `new Date().getTime()`)

Comment: I tried with and without window. and both times same error on when using built application. (on ng serve it works, on ng build it doesn't)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578530/failed-to-execute-atob-on-window)

Comment: Yep, I missed reading the error message. Duplicate suggests `atob()` produces this message when the passed data is not Base64. Consider checking if that token is not an error message or some other unexpected content.

Comment: Check my edited question. I think I solved problem but I would be very happy if someone could give me feedback if this solution is OK

Comment: `if(!this.tokenExpired(this.jwtToken || ''))` is the part where you can end up with passing an empty string, and then you have to deal with it inside `tokenExpired()`. I consider this suspicious, especially the latter part. If it is acceptable that the token does not exist, and the code should pass in that case, I would rather write the `if` as `if(!this.jwtToken || !this.tokenExpired(this.jwtToken))` and revert `tokenExpired()` to its original form.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
const expiry = JSON.parse(window.atob(token.split('.')[1])).exp;
```

Use

```
const expiry = JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1])).exp;
```

Comment: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

Comment: It looks like you are suggesting accessing `window` implicitly instead of explicitly. I don't see how that could help. If the variable was shadowed it might cause more problems.