# Convert DOM element to blob

Tags: javascript, file, pdf, dom, blob

I am trying to convert a dom element to Blob, which I want to use later for sending the same as attachment(as **pdf**). The code for the same is as following:

Dom element:

```
<div id="dom-container">
   Dom container
</div>
```

Code for dom to blob conversion: (in order to check the conversion, I am downloading as **PDF**)

```
const blobData = new Blob([document.getElementById('dom-container')], {type: "text/html"});
const a = document.createElement("a");
const object_URL = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
a.href = object_URL;
a.download = 'file.pdf';
a.click();
URL.revokeObjectURL(object_URL);
```

After opening the file.pdf, getting the below error:
[image]

Can someone please help me to figure out where is the issue while this dom to blob/pdf conversion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First off, PDFs are not HTML files. Secondly, you made a blob of a dom element, not its innerHTML.

Comment: @John Thanks for the comment. I tried with innerHTML as well but it didn't worked. Any way to make this work ?

Comment: Use pdf.js and understand how it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734072/creating-javascript-blob-with-data-from-html-element-then-downloading-it-as-a

Comment: @MatthewCook0485 Already tried with the solution but it didn't worked. The issue is related to pdf conversion/rendering