# What does "blob" mean in the `href` property in "<link>"?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webpack

I am using Webpack to pack the CSS file. In Chrome, I saw tags like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/ceb9a0bf-aa11-43a9-b04c-ee1bfe892954">
```

I find is `blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/ceb9a0bf-aa11-43a9-b04c-ee1bfe892954` not equal to `localhost:3000/ceb9a0bf-aa11-43a9-b04c-ee1bfe892954`, because I can't access the `localhost:3000/ceb9a0bf-aa11-43a9-b04c-ee1bfe892954` using Browser or Curl.

I tried to search MDN for what `blob` mean here. But I didn't find any information. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link