# Why the downloaded file is corrupted?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My webapp is using Spring MVC. Endpoint below allows user to download a file. When the user saves the file (Chrome, MSIE) in the browser it is broken. It size is 28792 bytes instead of 24567 and content seems to have different encoding. I spent a day trying to fix that but no success. Source file works fine. Please advise. Thanks a lot!

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void processFile(MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        response.setHeader("Content-Encoding","UTF-8");
        Files.copy(Paths.get("c:\\files", "worksheet.xls"), response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution works for me http://www.java2novice.com/issues/download-file-in-spring-rest-controller/

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to download a file, I think you should setup your `header` or `response` like this:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=worksheet.xls");
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem was in the [JavaScript on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328891/1071282) I used to ensure the download starts automatically. For somehow reason it broke file encoding. 
I finally solved the problem so that instead of writting data to response output stream I stored it in a temporary file and provided a link to it. Then I used [jQuery FileDownload plugin](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload) to download it. And it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in  [converter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#configureMessageConverters-java.util.List-), it is possible that your `ResponseEntity` is "converted". Look up configuration, for example in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. If any converter is used especially default ones (like json or xml):
put a break marker at every converter class `write` method to find out which converter is used.