# How to show download as prompt on new window from bootstrap model?

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-modal

For a normal HTML page I tried the below code which starts download in a separate window. When I use the same code for bootstrap modal form then it's not working. What else I need to do for implement same functionality in bootstrap modal ?

```
 var newwin=window.open("",'newwindow','width=700,height=700, left=100,top=100,resizable=yes','_blank').document;
    var link =newwin.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);                   
    link.download = fileName;
    link.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have used `blob` in `window.URL.createObjectURL`, which is undefined. 
you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38473396/5813861) solution.

use code like this :

```
var newwin=window.open("",'newwindow','width=700,height=700, left=100,top=100,resizable=yes','_blank').document;
var link =newwin.createElement('a');
var blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"});
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);                   
link.download = fileName
window.location.assign(url);
```