# download text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, blob

Like the title is saying, I'm trying to download a text file in javascript. Best way would be a .docx file but .txt is ok. I saw the blob framework and tried it but doesn't work.. Looks like it can't save my file.

My code to save my text file:

```
 function totxt(){
      var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
      saveAs(blob, "helloworld.txt");
 }
```

Comment: *Uncaught ReferenceError: saveAs is not defined(…)* — You're missing something significant there.

Comment: this might be helpfull for you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19328891/5047556

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgot to insert needed JS library files. You can find the demo in [this link](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js), like this:

```js
function totxt() {
  var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
  });
  saveAs(blob, "helloworld.txt");
}

$("#test").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  totxt();
});
```

```html
<body>

  <button id="test">press</button>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/Blob.js/0cef2746414269b16834878a8abc52eb9d53e6bd/Blob.js" />
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/e9d941381475b5df8b7d7691013401e171014e89/FileSaver.min.js" />

</body>
```