# How do I save a file getting downloaded from server using react?

Tags: reactjs

I have one backend API which basically downloads a template whenever we call it.
I have provided a href on my html page hence whenever someone click on that href, it calls backend API and that file should get downloaded.

But the file is not getting downloaded.

I am using React. If i simply hit the backend from my browser, file gets downloaded but if i call that from react, it doesn't.

Any leads?

**REACT CODE :**

```js
const config = require('config');
var aws4 = require('aws4');
const Promise = require('axios');

const requestHelper = {
  appendHeaders(request){
    request.headers = request.headers || {};
    if(request.headers["Content-Type"]){
      return
    }
    request.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
  },
  externalApi(request, serverResult){
    if(!request.method){
      request.method='POST';
    }
    request.path = request.url
    this.appendHeaders(request)
   console.log('request',request)
    return Promise(request)
    .then((apiResponse) => {
      if (apiResponse.data.errors) {
        var error = apiResponse.data.errors;
        console.log('api error response: ', error);
        serverResult.status(400).json({ error })
      } else {
        console.log('api response: ', apiResponse.data);
        serverResult.status(200).json(apiResponse.data);
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('api error response: ', error);
      serverResult.status(400).json({ error });
    });
   },

   getDownloadResponse(request, serverResult){
    debugger;
    request.path = request.url
    this.appendHeaders(request)
    console.log(request);
    return Promise(request)
    .then((apiResponse) => {
      if (apiResponse.data.errors) {
        var error = apiResponse.data.errors;
        console.log('api error response: ', error);
        serverResult.status(400).json({ error })
      } else {
        serverResult.status(200);
        console.log('api response status: '+200);
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('api error response: ', error);
      serverResult.status(400).json({ error });
    });
   }
};

module.exports = requestHelper;
```

**BACKEND API CODE :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = GlobalConstants.DOWNLOAD_FILE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadTemplate(HttpServletRequest hRequest, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(sampleFile)) {
            File file = new File(sampleFile);
            in = finderService.downloadFile(sampleFile);
            if (in != null) {
                MimetypesFileTypeMap mimetypesFileTypeMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
                response.setContentType(mimetypesFileTypeMap.getContentType(file));
                String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", file.getName());
                response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

                out = response.getOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int length;
                while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
            }
        } else {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        logger.error("Internal Server error"); //Add logs for server error here also

    } catch (Throwable th) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        logger.error(th);
        return;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Not enough details to answer you.

Comment: No Error as such. I am hitting the API but file is not getting downloaded. I think server side rendering would be required?

Comment: Then add some code maybe?

Comment: Sure. Uploading the code here.

Comment: Frontend code too, if possible (GET request..)

Comment: Updated. See the getDownloadResponse() method.

Comment: If I directly open the API URL in browser, file is getting downloaded. I just need to do that from a html page.

Comment: What kind of files will be downloaded? zip? images? Or pretty much anything?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A `GET` request in JS is not the same as visiting a url in your browser. You need to directly invoke a download on the client by specifying an URL, for example like this:

```js
download() {
  // fake server request, getting the file url as response
  setTimeout(() => {
    const response = {
      file: 'http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.5/ubuntu-12.04.5-alternate-amd64.iso',
    };
    // server sent the url to the file!
    // now, let's download:
    window.open(response.file);
    // you could also do:
    // window.location.href = response.file;
  }, 100);
}
```

Here it is as [a working example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jefuqum/edit?js,output).

**Note** that if you want to download files that the browser can display (such as JSON, images, videos), they will be displayed in a new tab. If you want those types of files downloaded directly, you will need to use some workarounds, for example using `blob`. There are [a few examples of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328891/6941627) on here.

Comment: Great. It worked. Thank you so much. Need one for help (I am new to the front end). How do I handle Connection refused in React? Say if backend is down.

Comment: In your Promise you have the `.catch((error))` function, in that you can handle the display of an error message to the user. You can also set a [timeout for axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#axioscreateconfig), if it doesn't get data after that time it will throw an error.

Comment: Why `setTimeout`?

Comment: It's just to show how it would work with an asynchronous request (e.g. `fetch`). In your code you won't need to use `setTimeout`.

Comment: This works great, but if the file is an image it just opens in the browser instead of downloading.. any way to get around this?

Comment: @EgorEgorov Check the "note" in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for providing additional link in the Note.

Answer (score 19):

You can use React 'a' element with `href` and `download` props:

```
 <a href={getFile.url}
    download={getFile.saveAsFileName}>
</a>
```

Comment: In React local development, also need to modify the local development server (Node) in order to resp the file. Thank you so much. I had researched for a couple of hours until I found your post.

Comment: This was very useful! More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download

Comment: this is the Best answer