# Generate and Download json file from reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, web-applications

Hello I am newly studying React JS

And, I am studying way to download json file from webapp

I try to find solution but I didn't understand..

[Converting Object into JSON and downloading as a .json file in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215642/converting-object-into-json-and-downloading-as-a-json-file-in-react)

[How do I save a file getting downloaded from server using react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707684/how-do-i-save-a-file-getting-downloaded-from-server-using-react)

here is my problem..

I have Constructor like..

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      Json_String: "{'None','none'}, 
      Project_NUM: "None"
    }

   }
```

and I have a method to get data from Mongo DB and using JSON.stringify to convert data to string type json....

```
  JsonBuilder() {           
      let {proj} = this.props;

         axios.get(SCongig.proj_Url, { params: {
        GuestID: proj.GuestID,
        Company_ID: proj.Company_ID
        }}, null)
      .then((res)=> {
         this.setState({...this.state,Json_String:  JSON.stringify(res.data[0])});
         this.setState({...this.state,Project_NUM:  proj.Company_ID});

      })

    }
```

And, I have javeacript part.. which button and download json with click event

```
  <a download={`TEST_ ${this.state.Project_NUM}.json`}  href={`data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,${this.state.Json_String.json}`}> 

   <Button
      shape="circle"
      icon="save"
      style={{border: 'none', background: 'none', width: 15, height: 15, marginLeft: 10}}
      onClick={this.JsonBuilder.bind(this)}       
    />
    </a>
```

However, I am getting two problems

**First, web app is trying to download json file  before passing**

```
 this.setState({...this.state,Json_String:  JSON.stringify(res.data[0])});
         this.setState({...this.state,Project_NUM:  proj.Company_ID});
```

I think, I need to assign json and Project_NUM to constructor, so I can download json file with click button event..

**Second, even though, I initialize constructor like "None" webapp is failing to download json file...**

I was thinking after I used  ".get" then it passes "res" to get data in Object
, so I can prepare to download json file..
however, I am not sure why... web is trying to download json file before passing **this.setState**. Is there anything mistake that I made ? or misunderstood concept of reactjs programming?