# How to add filename while using responseType: "blob"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

How to add filename while using responseType: "blob". It should show like test.csv.

My Code:

```
var account = API.one("users/csvExport", checkboxesChecked).withHttpConfig({responseType: "blob"}).post().then((response) => {
        var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(response);
        window.open(url,"_self");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Maybe dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript blob filename without link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link)