# How to download a blob data as file in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, blob, sapui5

Dear SAPUI5 developers,

How can I download a blob data as file in `SAPUI5`?

I have a **`blob object`**:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,MjU1MjE2MjU1MjI0MDE2NzQ3MDc....."
```

I can not use the normal method that we usually use in JavaScript.

I mean `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);` does not make a correct url for the blob data.

Can you tell me how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Mostly you used `sap.m.Link` for creating the download link. I know if you create a anchor (`a` tag in HTML) and want to inject it in the `body` element you will receive the following warning:

```
ESLint(sap-no-dom-insertion): Direct DOM insertion is forbidden!
```

But ignore the warning and create a `a` tag and inject it in the body.

There is a good solution here:

[JavaScript blob filename without link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link)

Answer (score 0):

You can create download link with object onfly and fire click event or user can click. Example: [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

Comment: This method does not work in SAPUI5 because it is MVC model and has its own routing. then creating a URL does not work in SAPUI5 application.