# Rename file saved to the file system with angular 2

Tags: file, angular, typescript, blob

I want to save a blob downloaded from a server onto the file system, so i use

```
window.open( window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob));
```

to save it. But when i do that, then the saved file gets a completly jumbled random name. 

Is there any way to give the saved file my own name?

EDIT:
Server side looks like this (Spring Data REST controller):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadFile/{fileName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadFile(@PathVariable(value="fileName") String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {    
    File file = getMyFile(fileName)

    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+file.getName());
    response.setContentType(Files.probeContentType(file.toPath()));
    response.setContentLengthLong(file.length());

    response.getOutputStream().write(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the filename in the response headers on the server side?

Comment: What do you mean? how can i set those when using window.open()?

Comment: Sorry I assumed you had control over the server side also.

Comment: Actually i do, i updated my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been searching for a similar answer myself and found several possibilities to save a downloaded file.

In your case you can use the `download` attribute of the `<a>` element:
`<a href="bloburl" download="filename"></a>`. You can dynamically add this element when for instance a button is clicked, and programmatically perform the click event.

```
 var a = document.createElement("a"),
     fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 a.style = "display:none";
 a.href = fileURL;
 a.download = fileName;
 window.document.body.appendChild(a);
 a.click();
 window.document.body.removeChild(a);
 URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
```

The `download` atrribute only has recent support: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

For older versions of IE, use

```
if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
}
```

Comment: I will try it out

Comment: No luck, nothing happens, no error message and no download prompt