# angularjs download corrupted zip file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob

in my angular application I need to download a zip file, the download starts regularly, but the client download a corrupted zip file, whose size is only 15 byte.
this is the code for the request:

```
$http.post('/api/download/',data, {
          dataType : "binary",
          processData : false,
          accept:'application/zip',
          Encoding: 'gzip',
          responseType:'arraybuffer'})
```

this is how I handle the successful response:

```
function() {
   var data = {}
   data.files = $scope.selectedFiles
   FileService.download(data,function(resp){
       var blob = new Blob([resp], {type: "application/octet-stream"})
       console.log('response',resp)
       FileSaver.saveAs(blob,'registrazioni.zip',(err) => {
                              console.log('saved success,error',err);
       })                     
   })
}
```

I read many similar questions, but theirs  solutions do not apply to me

Comment: There is a [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517619/angularjs-save-image-file-sent-from-web-api-2/42517789#42517789) that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Try check this bug on FileSaver in Github: [saving Zip file problems](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/156)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set the responseType to arraybuffer.See sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data. So your code will like this:

```
$http.post('/postUrlHere',{myParams}, {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
  .success(function (response) {
       var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
       var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
});
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.cont = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
```

In html Page:

```
<embed ng-src="{{cont}}" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></embed>
```

This code Will be help you to solve problem.