# Angular - How to download file from Web API on subscribe()

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

> In Angular I'm trying to download an excel file from my Web API Server

If I call my API from an `<a>` component just like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost:55820/api/download">Download</a>
```

The file downloads fine and without handling the response I get the desired behaviour:

[image: Success download]

How can I get the same result making the request from my Angular *DownloadService* and handling the result on `.subscribe()`?

```
this.downloadService.download()
      .subscribe(file => {/*What to put here for file downloading as above*/});
```

Note that the server creates the response like this:

```
byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "/files/" + "file.xlsx");
var dataStream = new MemoryStream(b);
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "File";
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("file.xlsx"));
return response;
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment above should work, but here is another way

```
.subscribe(file) {
  const blob = new Blob([file], { type: 'text/csv' }); // you can change the type
  const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: That works fine, but the name of the resulting file cannot be changed. I combined it with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235129/typescript-blob-filename-without-link/43235224) and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

try this work around:

```
.subscribe(file => 
{  
   const a = document.createElement('a');
   a.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');  
   a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file.data);  
   a.download = fileName + '.xlsx';  
   a.click(); 
   a.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add js-file-download library which supports all browsers

`npm install js-file-download --save`

you can use `window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);` but IE does not support it...

here is my code for downloading Excel files from the Backend

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';

const result: any = await axios.create().post("http://localhost:8080/file",
{
   responseType: "arraybuffer",
});

let blob = new Blob([result.data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "export.xlsx");
```