# When downloading image using XmlHttpRequest, I getting this error

Tags: javascript, download, xmlhttprequest

This is the code I'm following.

```
 storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
      // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

  // This can be downloaded directly:
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(event) {
    var blob = xhr.response;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  xhr.send();

  // Or inserted into an <img> element:
  var img = document.getElementById('myimg');
  img.src = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

But I can't download image file as it says:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

However, I'm successful in displaying the image in my `img` tag. It would be good if I could download it also.

I using localhost to run this.

**Updated:
This is the new error:**

> Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Please do not include the code in image...

Comment: the issue is a CORS issue - clearly the URL is not same origin as the page itself - whatever server the image is coming from obviously doesn't allow such requests - so ... what server serves the image? it's not `http://localhost:8000` is it

Comment: you've shown no information at all about the server that hosts the image, so, I can't make any suggestions ... searching for *enable cors* should give you information on how to enable cors in many scenarios

Comment: I'm sure google (or whatever search engine you want) would help you

Comment: Why are you making an http request for an image you already have? Use a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link

Answer (score 1):

You must add headers in your server:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```

For example, this will allow all domains for the methods specified and headers.

Comment: It is not a tip, it is the solution... if you don't have access to the server you must request the admins add your domain to get access to its resources from your domain.

Comment: Is the same error now caused by the allowed headers, in my response content-type header is only allowed