# Force download mp3 from an url on all browers. Javascript/jQuery/reactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm working for a project where I have to implement a functionality : mp3 download. I only got the hosted file url on Amazon S3 and when I click on a button it should trigger the download. 
I tried the download attribute for HTML5 but it doesn't work on mozilla, and its not possible for me.

```
<a href="www.myurl.cloudfront.net/mymp3.mp3" download> Download </a>
```

Do you guys have any solution to make it works on every browsers ? Or any other solutions..

Thanks !

Nael

Answer (score 0):

jQuery and React don't really work well together, at least not manipulating DOM nodes.

If you are using jQuery to do AJAX calls and React as your view layer, you could hook up an onClick handler to your tag so that when the user clicks, you get an AJAX request to wherever you want:

```
class YourComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  handleClick(evt) {
    const { currentTarget } = evt;
    // currentTarget holds information of where you clicked, you can get your url from here
    $.ajax({
      //Your ajax call here
    }).then(data => //Handle your data, setState, etc.)
  }
  render() {
    <div>
      //Everything else
      <a onClick={this.handleClick} url='...'> Download</a>
    </div>
  }
};
```

Comment: Ok but how can I download the hosted mp3 even in AJAX ?

Comment: I believe you can use `window.open(url)` and that should trigger a download

Comment: No, the problem with mp3 files it that window.open() or other things like href, etc.. just open an html5 player

Comment: check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link/19328891#19328891