# How to dynamically create downloadable link from user uploaded files (disregarding file types) without calling server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<input id="browse" type="file" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var elBrowse = document.getElementById("browse");
var elPreview = document.getElementById("preview");

function readFile(file) {
    //Create downloadable link and generate DOM elements.
    var fileName = file.name;
    elPreview.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<a>" + fileName + '</a>');
    elPreview.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<a>Delete</a><br>");
}

elBrowse.addEventListener("change", function () {
    var files = this.files;

    // Check for `files` (FileList) support and if contains at least one file:
    if (files && files[0]) {

        // Iterate over every File object in the FileList array
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            readFile(file);
        }
    }

});
```

I am facing a new requirement, but I don't have much experience in Javascript. Basically, I want users to be able to upload files by clicking the browse button and displays the files name with downloadable link. User can upload **files of any type** and be able to **download the files back**.

The whole process M**UST not trigger the backend server** and **everything has to be done in javascript or JQuery**. Could anyone help please? Thank you.

System and User interaction:

1. User uploads a file
2. System saves the file in javascript and displays the file name with downloadable link.
3. User delete it.
4. System removes it from DOM and javascript
5. User can repeat step 1-4. The whole process does not trigger the server at all.
6. Eventually, user submits all the files to the server by clicking somewhere else (This step is out of the scope of this post)

Comment: BUT... you upload the file to the server! So.. the server is already  triggered.. right? Perhaps you wish to fetch the download link within your code?

Comment: Eventually, yes, user will submit the files to the server, but the intermediate steps do not trigger any server calls. Please see the system-user updates.

Comment: I think that you need to use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` for that kind of task (instead of "upload")

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this direction. It would be great if you could provide some sample code. How could I serve these locally stored files as downloadable links?

Comment: No need..there is already a great answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a modern browser then you can utilize the HTML5 FileReader.  I've used it, but found an example more suited to your question [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api).

You can use the FileReader to read the files on the client side, and store in sessionStorage, localStorage, or even a variable.  But the one caveat is that you'll probably run out of RAM because JavaScript's not really designed for retaining large BLOBs in RAM.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
  var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   var file = fileInput.files[0];
   var textType = /text.*/;

   if (file.type.match(textType)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
     fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
    }

    reader.readAsText(file); 
   } else {
    fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
   }
  });
}
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #333;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  border-top: 5px solid #69c773;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

h1 {
 margin-top: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#fileDisplayArea {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">

  <h1>Text File Reader</h1>
  <div>
   Select a text file: 
   <input type="file" id="fileInput">
  </div>
  <pre id="fileDisplayArea"><pre>

 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry. This is not the correct answer. It is stated clearly that the files being uploaded can be any types of files, not only text files.

Comment: @Xinwen I found you this example, but it's your job to customize it for your needs.

Comment: How does hard coded file type help me create my own code? This post also does not generate links nor using any local storage. Please read the requirements before just copying someone's code on the internet.

Comment: Hey pal.  I think you have something confused.  StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.  Let's not overlook the fact that there are NO other responses.  This example here is a skeleton for you to be able to read file contents in JS, which is something you'll need.  Don't like the hard-coded file type?  Then *change the code*.  But past being able to read the file in JS, you have to do the rest of the the work.  Do you have another solution?  Doubtful.  Maybe you can show a little appreciation instead of showing yourself to be an ungratious jerk.  **You're welcome.**

Comment: `var textType = /text.*/` is all you need to change for the file type.  Good luck.