# TCPDF returning weird characters

Tags: php, html, ajax, extjs, tcpdf

maybe you can help me. When I try to show a pdf I created I got some weird symbols like this

```
u\>�'���O���r>c!%�@�R�`YPd+��vv����1��E�'^k-�WD�*+��W^��wy��V Z��dUdJ�B���C�ڳtK����j:c���5����50���D3lgH#�}%���D+������ix����,��-�'\�� �_st^&0�Y���������v�*Ӗ,W����u!H��sNN��0cӝ��`xEk��d��^� �8K9�BL����9�̋"6/�E�|�̛�-�7�P��B�#�T�F���4`����
```

What I do is transform a html file with this code

```
    $html = $this->load->view('ReporteIngresoView', $data, TRUE);
    $pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', TRUE, 'UTF-8', FALSE);
    $pdf->SetTitle('Reporte ingreso');
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(30);
    $pdf->SetTopMargin(40);
    $pdf->setFooterMargin(20);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Pontificia Universidad Católica del Ecuador');
    $pdf->SetDisplayMode('real', 'default');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, TRUE, 0, TRUE, 0);
    $pdf->Output('My-File-Name.pdf', 'I');
```

On the other side I recieve it like this

```
Ext.Ajax.request
            (
                {
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '../servidor/archivo/ingreso/getreporte',
                    success: function(response){
                    Ext.getCmp('winReporteRegistro').update( response.responseText );
                       }
                    }
            );
```

I am using php (server), html (create the page), extjs (interface), ajax (request) and TCPDF to create the pdf.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Maybe its encoding issues? Check this to find convertion by "weird symbols" https://habrastorage.org/storage2/61b/e7a/455/61be7a4552a6650bd19b526db63d4779.png Its in russian, but I think you can easy understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning the location of the file and open that in another web page was the answer, the code is:

Server:

```
$html = $this->load->view('ReporteCajaView', $data, TRUE);

    $pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', TRUE, 'UTF-8', FALSE);
    $pdf->SetTitle('Reporte item');
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(30);
    $pdf->SetTopMargin(20);
    $pdf->setFooterMargin(20);
    $pdf->SetMargins(25, 20, 20, true);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Universidad Católica');
    $pdf->SetDisplayMode('real', 'default');
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(FALSE);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(FALSE);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $id = uniqid();
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, TRUE, 0, TRUE, 0);
    $pathservidor = 'c:/wamp64/www/Archivo/pdf/';
    $pdf->Output($pathservidor . 'Reporte de caja' . '.pdf', 'F');

    echo 'c:/wamp64/www/Archivo/pdf/'.'Reporte de caja'.'.pdf';
```

Client:

```
Ext.Ajax.request
            (
                {
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '../servidor/archivo/item/getreporte',

                    success: function(response){
                    window.open(response.responseText);

                       }
                }
            );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the response to a Blob ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob))

After creating the blob, you can create an URL object ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL))

This is how I create a server side generated pdf and display it on the front end.

Adding code snippet:

```
var blob = new Blob(response.responseText, {type: 'application/pdf'}); 
var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Something like this? var blob = new Blob(response.responseText);
                        objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);    
                        Ext.getCmp('winReporteRegistro').update(objectURL); The window is not showhing anything :(

Comment: close to what i have.

    var blob = new Blob(response.responseText, {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

Once you have an object URL, you can show it as a download link or download the pdf directly. Also found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link)

Comment: I tried to add a window var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'component',
            autoEl: {
                tag: 'a',
                href: objectURL,
                html: 'Example.com'
            } To show the hyperlink but still no luck. The window doesn't appear

Comment: can you just do a simple `window.open(objectURL);` It should open it in a new browser window

Comment: It doesn't work, nothing happens. Ext.Ajax.request ( {method: 'post',url: '../servidor/archivo/ingreso/getreporte',success: function(response){ var blob = new Blob(response.responseText, {type: 'application/pdf'}); var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);                                                    
                        window.open(objectURL);                                               
                        },
                     }
                ); I don't know why..

Comment: can you debug and see what is being returned in your success response? could be something to do with the response and creating the blob?

Comment: Yes, I used $pathservidor = 'c:/wamp64/www/Archivo/pdf/';
        $pdf->Output($pathservidor . uniqid() . '.pdf', 'F'); and it creates an empty pdf file in that directory

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer but I broke my teeth on this yesterday and this morning I had an illumination :-)
You need to support the mime-type so simply add this in your .htaccess:

```
AddType application/pdf .pdf
```