# Create and download a simple file

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is obviously a simplified test but if this works I'm able to do mine.

I want to create a file with string `code` and download the txt file.

The txt file should have `bla bla bla`

```js
$("button[id^='downloadTestCase-']").click(function() {
  var code = "bla bla bla"
  var file = new Blob([code], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  window.open(URL.createObjectURL(file));


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger-outline" id="downloadTestCase-Teste50" name="Teste50">Download</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a hidden `<a>` tag.
2. Set its href attribute to the blob's URL.
3. Set its download attribute to the filename.
4. Click on the `<a>` tag.

```js
$("button[id^='downloadTestCase-']").click(function() {
  var data = "bla bla bla"
  var fileName = "code"
 saveData(data, fileName);


});


var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
           var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "text/plain"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger-outline" id="downloadTestCase-Teste50" name="Teste50">Download</button>
```

This is based on an answer on Stack found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link)

Answer (score 1):

You need two separate code blocks, since IE uses [msSaveBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779016(v=vs.85).aspx):

```js
document.getElementById('downloadTestCase-Teste50')
    .addEventListener('click', function () {
    var blob = new Blob(
        ['bla bla bla'],
        { type: 'text/plain' }
    );
    var filename = 'result.txt';
    if (window.navigator
        && typeof window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob === 'function') {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    }
    else {
        var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = objectURL;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
    }
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger-outline" id="downloadTestCase-Teste50" name="Teste50">Download</button>
```