# Automatic Multiple Download No Longer Working On Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download, click

We produce browser based communication software that companies use for consultations. At the end of a consultation, the consultant can download recordings of the video streams. Since Chrome updated to version 65, the multiple file download only offers the last file.

We show a list of saved sessions & when the user clicks "Download" we loop through all recordings for that session and download them like in this SO solution:
[JavaScript blob filename without link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link)

```
var saveBlobAs = function(blob, filename){
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = 'display: none';
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };

for(var i = 0; i < matchedRecordings.length; i++){
        var recording = matchedRecordings[i];
        saveBlobAs(recording.blob, fileName);
    }
```

The code still works perfectly on FireFox but Chrome 65 only ever offers the last file. I could fix it by changing the link creation to

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = 'display: none';
a.href = url;
a.target = '_BLANK'; // Added this
a.download = filename;
a.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

But now Chrome sees it as a popup and opens new tabs for each file.

Has anybody else had the same problem? Is there a better solution than opening each link in a new tab?

Comment: Having the same problem without a solution at the moment.

Comment: This is what the [Chrome support forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/NlVjxZFfYDk/bYEXz9fRBgAJ) says "Chrome 65 has disabled multiple downloads from websites and maintains a consistent functionality the same as Firefox browser."

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to add a pause to get around chrome detecting multiple downloads. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/q65u3gsk/71/) with buttons with and without pauses.

I never got the "only last file" issue, but it did stop after the tenth file. Adding a pause made all download dialogs appear (chrome 68).

Get rid of the `target` and implement the loop with an `await` (or some sort of hideous `Promise` callback thing if you need to support <ES6).

So you'd call with `saveBlobs(matchedRecordings, 200)`, but you might need to change the function a little since your data has a `.blob` and all share the same filename, apparently.

```js
async function saveBlobs(blobs, wait) {
  for (let blob of blobs) {
    saveBlob(blob[0], blob[1]);
    if (wait)
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), wait));
  }
}

function saveBlob(blob, name) {
  //create the initiator
  var download = document.createElement('a');
  download.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  download.download = name;

  //fire it off
  document.body.appendChild(download);
  download.click();
  setTimeout(() => download.remove());
}
```