# Download a CSV file in Javascript (or Symfony) from a Base64

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, csv, base64

I'm using a method to download a CSV file from a Base64.

```
var dlnk = document.getElementById("myDownloadButton");
dlnk.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + myBase64;
dlnk.click();
```

It worked until I realized that when the base64 is too long, I have a problem. It will open a white page and it won't download my CSV file. I think it's because my base64 is too long.

Do you have an alternative in JavaScript or in Symfony 3?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of creating a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) from the data, create a [Blob Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). This will avoid the 33% extra overhead of base64 encoding.

Comment: Example here with Blob Object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link/19328891#19328891

Comment: Thank you for your answers but it doesn't work with a large base64 (length more than 3472174 characters)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution:

```
let csvContent = atob("YOUR BASE64");
var blob = new Blob([csvContent], {type: "data:application/octet-stream;base64"});
var url  = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// you need to precise a front-end button to have a name
var dlnk = document.getElementById(nameFile);
dlnk.href = url;
dlnk.click();
```