# Can't open blob files in firefox

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf, firefox, blob

I want to open files sent from server on Firefox.

Actually it's working on IE. Here's how I would proceed:

```
openFile(path, fileName) {
  this.creditPoliciesService
    .openFile(path)
    .toPromise()
    .then(data => {
      var blob = new Blob([data.body], { type: "application/pdf" });
      if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { //if navigator is IE
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
      } else { // Mozilla case
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob); //URL.createObjectURL takes only one parameter.
        window.open(fileURL);
      }
    });
}
```

When I open file I get in new tab a blob adress `blob:http://localhost:4200/90907276-947a-47d8-873d-40163` with an empty page

I think I should pass file name but it's not possible with `URL.createObjectURL`

How can I open files in right format ?

- in Chrome : files get opened but without a file name at the top bar, I get "XXXXXX" instead.
- in Firefox : as mentioned I get blob address at the navigation bar with an empty page.
- in IE : it's working

Comment: You keep using the word "Mozilla" and have tagged this [tag:mozilla] which says *DO NOT USE THIS TAG, it is going to be removed. The Mozilla Foundation is a non-profit organization that exists to support and provide leadership for the open source Mozilla project.* Did you mean [tag:firefox]?

Comment: You have tagged this [tag:createObject] but that doesn't seem to have anything to do with this question.

Comment: You've mentioned IE and "Mozilla", but have you tested in any other browsers? It is normally useful to determine which share a common behaviour and which are the outliers. This often makes it easier to track down the problem.

Comment: I have modified the question..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19327749/1427878 has a way to specify the file name - but check carefully whether that works under all circumstances where you need it, because browser vendors have started placing certain limitations on this.

Comment: And that you get an “empty window” is default browser behavior for “downloaded” resources - not particular to your specific way of triggering the download here, `<a href="download.file" target=_"blank">` would have the same effect. If you don’t want that … well then _don’t_ open it in a _new window_ to begin with, but assign it to `location.href` instead.