# Javascript: Saving getUserMedia() images

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, blob, webcam, getusermedia

I want to load the user's webcam to a canvas, and then save an image from that canvas as a blob.  Hopefully, I will get 1 image every 1 second.

Unfortunately, I only get 1 image saved 5 times, rather than 5 different images.  My code is fairly straightforward, but I suspect the issue is with my `takeASnap()` function.  What is going wrong?

**Edit:** This is observed on Safari on iPad/iPhone, but not in desktop chrome.

```
var NUM_IMAGES = 5;
    const vid = document.querySelector('video');
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }) // request cam
        .then(stream => {
            vid.srcObject = stream; // don't use createObjectURL(MediaStream)
            return vid.play(); // returns a Promise
        })
        .then(() => { // enable the button
            const btn = document.getElementById('download-button');
            btn.disabled = false;
            btn.onclick = e => {
                imageId = 0;
                userId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
                recursiveDelay(kickOff, NUM_IMAGES, 1000)

            };
        });

    function kickOff() {
        takeASnap().then(saveBlob); // saveBlob out of scope of this question.
    }

    function recursiveDelay(functionToCall, executionsNumber, timeoutInMilliseconds) {
        if (executionsNumber) { //exit condition
            functionToCall(); // external function execution
            setTimeout(
                () => {
                    recursiveDelay(functionToCall, executionsNumber - 1, timeoutInMilliseconds); //recursive call
                }, timeoutInMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    function takeASnap() {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); // create a canvas
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // get its context
        canvas.width = vid.videoWidth; // set its size to the one of the video
        canvas.height = vid.videoHeight;
        ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0); // the video

        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            canvas.toBlob(res, 'image/jpeg'); // request a Blob from the canvas
        });

    }
```

Comment: Why not use [webcamjs](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs)?

Comment: I personally use the [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver/v/1.3.2) package, but the implementation is basically a variation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript blob filename without link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link)

Comment: See edit: this problem is observed on safari mobile but not in chrome on desktop.