# Angular - Save blob in local text file?

Tags: javascript, angular, blob

I have a plain text variable which I want to store and save on a `.txt` file using Angular.

So far I have tried the following:

```
var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
window.open(url);
```

Being `text` the variable with the plain text content. It seems to work but it opens de blob on a new browser tab, and I need it to be downloaded as `whatever.txt`.

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Check this one out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link

Comment: Finally found the solution here: [JavaScript blob filename without link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328891/10143290)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution can be found here:

[JavaScript blob filename without link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328891/10143290)

The steps are the following:

1. Create a hidden `<a>` tag.
2. Set its `href` attribute to the blob's URL.
3. Set its `download` attribute to the filename.
4. Click on the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

This is working code from my application

```
const file = new window.Blob([data], { type: contentType });

const downloadAncher = document.createElement("a");
downloadAncher.style.display = "none";

const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  downloadAncher.href = fileURL;
  downloadAncher.download = fileName;
  downloadAncher.click();
```

Comment: can you share a https://stackblitz.com/ example? Having a live example would help