# Javascript Blob writing string instead of binary

Tags: javascript, blob

I am receiving an excel file from an api call and need to save it to the user's computer. I have been trying to do this by creating a blob from it and downloading that, but for some reason the blob converts the binary data to a string somewhere in the process and then saves the binary of the string.

The function I am using is

```
function saveFile(raw)
{
    var excel = new Blob([raw], {type: mimeType});

    const data = const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = data;
    link.download="transactions.xlsx";
    link.click();
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
    }, 100);
}
```

and I have tried both "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" and "octet/stream" for mimeType.

The result either way is that the first several bytes of the correct file are

```
50 45 03 04 14 00 08 08
```

which is displayed as "PK......" in a hex editor, whereas the first several bytes of what I am getting from my function are

```
50 4B 5C 75 30 30 30 33 5C 75 30 30 30 34
```

which is displayed as "PK\u0003\u0004"

At first I thought it was an error in how the data was being transmitted as the type header of the return was "application/json", but when I wrote a function to step through the response byte by byte to "fix" it being a string I found that prior to creating the blob that data was correct. Am I missing something about using blobs?

Comment: From the snippet you've attached it seems that you don't actually set the mime type...

Comment: Also, you may not need to do anything with the rawData, just call `createObjectURL` directly on it.

Comment: In my actual code instead of it being ```new Blob([raw], {type: mimeType});``` it is either ```new Blob([raw], {type:  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});``` or ```new Blob([raw], {type: "octet/stream"});```

Comment: Don't know if it changes anything but most examples here: (the SO question where I learned how to do it from) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link attach the link element to the body before clicking it.