# JS built CSV breaking after # in Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, special-characters

I'm building CSVs via JavaScript and some of the cell values contain hashtags and other special characters. I have noticed in particular that the hashtags act as a hard stop for the file. I have not been able to find a solution online, nor have I really seen this specific issue. I have tried the `\uFEFF` fix, but to no avail. Below is the function I use to build my CSVs.

```
export const buildCSV = (headers, data) => {
  if (!headers && !data) return;

  let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,";

  if (headers) {
    csvContent += headers.join(",") + "\r\n";
  }

  if (data) {
    data.forEach(row => {
      csvContent += row.join(",") + "\r\n";
    });
  }

  return encodeURI(csvContent);
};
```

For reference, currently, a value such as `150 # content` will show up as `150` and the rest of the rows are cutoff when opening the CSV.

Thank you in advance to anyone that takes the time to provide an answer!

Comment: why `encodeURI`?

Comment: So the user can download the created file using an `<a>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by making this switch:

```
  const encodedURI = encodeURI(csvContent);
  const fixedEncodedURI = encodedURI.replaceAll('#', '%23');
  return fixedEncodedURI;
```

Performing the switch prior to running encodeURI caused the result to be "%23" instead of correctly converting it back to a hashtag. According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI#Description), the `encodeURI` function doesn't escape hashtags (among other characters, however I haven't noticed an issue with the other characters). After manually encoding them, they are converted back to hashtags once downloaded and opened in Excel.

TKoL created a fiddle showing the use of `encodeURIComponent` resulting in the desired output. Some things to note, as I ran into an issue attempting to use this function, is that the following changes must be made to the initial code or it will result in a failed download:

```
let csvContent = "";

other code...

return "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(csvContent);
```

Thank you to all that provided potential solutions!

Comment: I will accept this answer once the system allows me, which is apparently in 2 days.

Comment: What about `encodeURIComponent`, which does replace hashtags?

Comment: I made [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gxsp75o/1/) to test `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Hm, that does indeed work. It seems my issue when attempting that solution was that if `data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,` is added to the `csvContent` variable before `encodeURIComponent` is ran, it results in a failed download. However, apparently if you add the data specification to the result of `encodeURIComponent` it functions as expected.

Comment: Have you considered making the uri out of a blob instead? https://gist.github.com/dhunmoon/d743b327c673b589e7acfcbc5633ff4b

Answer (score 1):

Picked clues from an answer here [JavaScript blob filename without link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link).

The below given minimal reproduction of your code seems to be working. It relies on download attribute in HTML5. So, does not support older browsers. But If you want that support, above link has more answers you can check.

```
<script>
 const buildCSV = (headers, data) => {
  if (!headers && !data) return;

  let csvContent = "";

  if (headers) {
    csvContent += headers.join(",") + "\r\n";
  }

  if (data) {
    data.forEach(row => {
      csvContent += row.join(",") + "\r\n";
    });
  }
return csvContent;
}

function downloadFile()
{
 function download(data, fileName) {
      var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
            blob = new Blob([data], {type: "text/csv"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
var data = buildCSV(['header1','header2','header3'],[['150#content','rowvalue1','rowvalue2']]),
    fileName = "myfile.csv";
    download(data, fileName);
}

</script>
<body>
<a href="" onclick="downloadFile()" >Download</a>
</body>
```