# Can I download an image if it's in base64 format?

Tags: reactjs, base64

I'm developing a React App, and I have a backend in NodeJS.
In my Mongo Schema I have an array that stores multiple strings, these strings are some images.
I saved them as base64. Now I want to display them in my app, works perfectly fine with src from img tag, but I want to create a button that allows the user to download those pictures, is there any solution to this? Can I convert back that string and make it downloadable? Thank you very much for you time, I'm waiting for your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: The examples in the snippets will not work live because Stack Overflow sandboxes snippets without `allow-downloads`, but they should work on your page.*

Depending on your exact use case, you have different options. The easiest one would be using an `<a>` tag with the `download` attribute instead of a button, like this:

```html
<a download="myImage.gif" href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhEAAQAMwAAPj7+FmhUYjNfGuxYYDJdYTIeanOpT+DOTuANXi/bGOrWj6CONzv2sPjv2CmV1unU4zPgISg6DJnJ3ImTh8Mtbs00aNP1CZSGy0YqLEn47RgXW8amasW7XWsmmvX2iuXiwAAAAAEAAQAAAFVyAgjmRpnihqGCkpDQPbGkNUOFk6DZqgHCNGg2T4QAQBoIiRSAwBE4VA4FACKgkB5NGReASFZEmxsQ0whPDi9BiACYQAInXhwOUtgCUQoORFCGt/g4QAIQA7">Download GIF</a>
```

If you need to keep using a button and you want to trigger the download programmatically, you can create an `<a>` tag (without displaying it) and trigger a click:

```js
const a = document.createElement('a')
a.download = 'myImage.gif'
a.href = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhEAAQAMwAAPj7+FmhUYjNfGuxYYDJdYTIeanOpT+DOTuANXi/bGOrWj6CONzv2sPjv2CmV1unU4zPgISg6DJnJ3ImTh8Mtbs00aNP1CZSGy0YqLEn47RgXW8amasW7XWsmmvX2iuXiwAAAAAEAAQAAAFVyAgjmRpnihqGCkpDQPbGkNUOFk6DZqgHCNGg2T4QAQBoIiRSAwBE4VA4FACKgkB5NGReASFZEmxsQ0whPDi9BiACYQAInXhwOUtgCUQoORFCGt/g4QAIQA7'
a.click()
```

(If you need to support older browsers, you may have to temporarily insert the tag into the DOM and trigger the click in a `setTimeout(..., 0)`.)

You can also use object URLs like it's [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968694/1871033) but it's probably easier to go the data URI route since you already have such a URI.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but it seems I had some misspellings, and that's why it didn't work. Thank you very much!