# How do I create/save/edit a txt file with an google chrome extension CODE?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hi I tried to save/edit/create a file as I am used to with js.
However nothing is working in the chrome extension.

Does someone know how to do it?
I looked here on stackover and did not found satisfied results.

Comment: Chrome extensions cannot create/modify local files.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko thanks but how can I import files? Is there an option to save it in the chrome data and afterwards crawl/open it with another program?

Comment: You can dynamically create and initiate file download in browser, then use any program from there on, on the local system, to read the file from downloads directory.

Comment: @Neea thanks for your answer, what would be the shortest js code to generate this type of download files?

Comment: see this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328891/4054683