# How to download Promise<Blob> with browser instead of Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am getting my file from firebase server by

```
getBlob(ref(this.str, `xxx.xx`)); // returns Promise<Blob>
```

but just calling it directly, it will get downloaded as an internal file
[image]

How do I do it so that it gets download externally
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328891/16914936

Comment: @AmanSharma That doesn't solve my problem at all... the function is a `Promise<blob>`