# Download PDF from javascript blob, without replacing the open page

Tags: javascript, pdf, download

I have a PDF being generated in the browser, and converted to a blob object. The "traditional" method of downloading this by using javascript to inject an `a` tag (example code below) opens the PDF in the browser, however this replaces the page the user had open causing them to lose any unsaved work. Adding `target="_blank"` doesn't change this, and the document still opens in the same tab.

```js
const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: "application/pdf" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
anchorElement.href = url;
anchorElement.download = fileName;
anchorElement.target = "_blank";

anchorElement.click();
anchorElement.remove();
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

I'd be happy with either opening the PDF in a new tab, or forcing it to be downloaded. As the PDF isn't being loaded from a URL, it's not possible to set any headers on it.

Comment: afaik the download attribute is the key here and you set it already... so the only question arising is: did you correctly populate the fileName var with a valid string? There's a detailed discussion here about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link ... and also more in general here: https://blog.logrocket.com/programmatic-file-downloads-in-the-browser-9a5186298d5c/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually found a solution, incorrectly setting the MIME type on the blob breaks the browser's file type detection, and stops the built-in preview from starting.

```js
const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try;

```
const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: "application/pdf" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the name the file is saved as with this methid?

Comment: No, it is not possible to set the name.