# How do I allow for copying data to clipboard from .NET Interactive (Polyglot) Notebooks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, f#, deedle, .net-interactive

I am working in .NET Interactive (aka Polyglot) Notebooks in F# (but I believe the same would apply to C#). In my code, I am running functions that ultimately produce an F# list of floating point values, or alternatively might be an F# list of tuples which contain floating point values.

When I ask the notebook to display the variable, it shows the first 20 values and says ".. (more)." Ideally, I would like to either be able to download this data by pressing a link next to the table that's displayed, or alternatively, run some function that can copy the full data to the clipboard - similar to Pandas' to_clipboard function.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a cell that, when run, copies the contents of a data frame to a clipboard, you can do this using the `TextCopy` package. For testing, I used the following (including also Deedle and extension for nicely rendering frames):

```
#i "nuget:https://www.myget.org/F/gregs-experimental-packages/api/v3/index.json"
#r "nuget:Deedle"
#r "nuget:Deedle.DotNet.Interactive.Extension,0.1.0-alpha9"
#r "nuget:TextCopy"
open Deedle
```

Let's create a sample data frame and a function to get its contents as CSV string:

```
let df = 
 Frame.ofRecords
  [ for i in 0 .. 100 -> {| Name = $"Joe {i}" |} ]

let getFrameAsCsv (df:Frame<_, _>) = 
  let sb = System.Text.StringBuilder()
  use sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb)
  df.SaveCsv(sw)
  sb.ToString()
```

To copy `df` to the clipboard, you can run:

```
TextCopy.ClipboardService.SetText(getFrameAsCsv df)
```

If you want to create a download link in the notebook output, this is also possible. You can use the `HTML` helper to output custom HTML and inside that, you can use the `data:` format to embed your CSV as a linked file in `<a href=...>` (as long as it is not too big):

```
let csv = 
  System.Convert.ToBase64String
    (System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(getFrameAsCsv df))
HTML($"<a href='data:text/csv;name=file.csv;base64,{csv}'>Download CSV</a>")
```

Comment: Thanks so much. And I think in theory you can get past the "not too big" limit by creating a Blob in JS, but I haven't tried it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327749/javascript-blob-filename-without-link/19328891#19328891