# Download response as an excel file

Tags: angularjs, spring, servlets, spring-boot, apache-poi

File is not downloading at browser. I'm preparing the file and writing it to output stream of response.

Rest API is there:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/export-companies",
        method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
    @Timed
    public void downloadCompanies(HttpServletResponse response) throws URISyntaxException {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");

        Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
        data.put("1", new Object[] {"Emp No.", "Name", "Salary"});
        data.put("2", new Object[] {1d, "John", 1500000d});
        data.put("3", new Object[] {2d, "Sam", 800000d});
        data.put("4", new Object[] {3d, "Dean", 700000d});

        Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                if(obj instanceof Date)
                    cell.setCellValue((Date)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Boolean)
                    cell.setCellValue((Boolean)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Double)
                    cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
            }
        }

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            workbook.write(outByteStream);
            byte [] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();
            response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
            response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
            response.setHeader("Expires:", "0"); // eliminates browser caching
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=template.xls");
            OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
            outStream.write(outArray);
            outStream.flush();
            workbook.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

From front end (using Angular JS):

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('MyApp')
        .factory('CompanyExportService', CompanyExportService);

    CompanyExportService.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function CompanyExportService ($resource) {
        var service = $resource('api/export-companies', {}, {
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false
            }
        });

        return service;
    }
})();
```

File contents are there in response as non-readable format. But file is not downloaded at browser.

Comment: i have done the same code but a minor change response.setContentType("application/force-download");
 it worked in chrome browser, i didn't tested in other browsers

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 5):

Angular will receive the file contents mere character sequences. You need to create a file from these characters and initiate the browser download in frontend.

You can do it like this -

```
var blob = new Blob([data], 
                    {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformat-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;'});
saveAs(blob, fileName);
```

where `data` is the response you received form your API. The `saveAs` function is part of [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library. Although you can look on how to manually do that but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I use this same code to save excel file that returned from response.build() method of Response object of rest api. Although it save file, but while I try to open the saved excel file, it show  file corrupt error message.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? am facing the same issue.

Comment: This works for me. Just one question though. How do I retain the filename sent by server? That is  I don't wanna supply my own `fileName` in `saveAs(blob, fileName)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Downloading files with XHR is problematic. As long as you do only GET requests, there exists much simpler approach to trigger browser to download file.

Use JavaScript native method `window.open(url)`.
It does work well in all browsers including IE9.

In code below, I use `$window`, which is Angular's proxy for native window object.

Example for your code could be like:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .factory('CompanyExportService', CompanyExportService);

CompanyExportService.$inject = ['$window'];

function CompanyExportService ($window) {
    var exportUrl = 'api/export-companies';

    return {
        download: download
    }

    function download() {
        $window.open(exportUrl);
    }
}
})();
```

Note that this action is out of scope of Angular, you can't do much about error handling or waiting till the file will be downloaded. Might be problem if you want to generate huge Excel files or your API is slow.

For more details, read question: [Spring - download response as a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177303/spring-download-response-as-a-file)

Update:

I've replaced `window.location.href` with `window.open()` which seems to be better choice for downloading files.

If your API will throw an error page instead of file, `window.location.href` will replace current page (thus losing its state). `$window.open()` however will opens this error in new tab without losing current state of of application.

Comment: hi @Piotr Lewandowski kindly check my fiddle once https://jsfiddle.net/x30v0bym/3/  file download is wokring correctly but excel not open properly in microsoft excel i am not getting cells it's show data with white paper help

Comment: @jose your problem is that you don't generate content in appropriate format. You've only saved HTML into file and named it with *xls* extension. It won't auto-magically be converted into excel file format. *Ask another question* as it's much more space needed to describe proper way of doing it.

Comment: @jose I found you already asked question. I've answered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44602960/2757140

Answer (score 3):

You can download file in new tab. Modern browser are closing them automatically when downloading is completed.

By opening new window you get reference to it, when downloading is completed then `window.closed` is set to true.

Unfortunatelly you need to check from time-to-time this param inside interval ...

```
var newWindowRef = $window.open(url, name);
if (newWindowRef) {
    if (newWindowRef.document.body) { // not working on IE
        newWindowRef.document.title = "Downloading ...";
        newWindowRef.document.body.innerHTML = '<h4>Your file is generating ... please wait</h4>';
    }

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (!!newWindowRef.closed) {
            // Downloading completed
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1000);
} else {
    $log.error("Opening new window is probably blocked");
}
```

Tested and works on Chrome v52, FF v48 and IE 11