# Excel download in Browser: Not able to prompt out save button

Tags: java, browser, download

I expected it will have a prompt-out screen to asking user to Open or Save or Cancel.

From below my code, i try FileOutputStream is work to save the file into a specific location, but how can i do something like below my screenshot?

Expected screenshot: 
[image]

Below is my code:

```
try {
    /* Create Workbook and Worksheet XLSX Format */
    XSSFWorkbook my_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet my_sheet = my_workbook.createSheet("Cell Font");
    /* Get access to XSSFCellStyle */
    XSSFCellStyle my_style = my_workbook.createCellStyle();

    /* We will now specify a background cell color */
    my_style.setFillPattern(XSSFCellStyle.FINE_DOTS);
    my_style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
    my_style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());

    /* Create a row in the sheet */
    Row row = my_sheet.createRow(0);
    /* Create a cell */
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Cell Fill Color Test");
    /* Attach the style to the cell */
    cell.setCellStyle(my_style);

    /* Write changes to the workbook */
    // OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
    // new File(ExcelConstant.TEST));
    // my_workbook.write(out);
    // out.close();

    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
    // response.setContentType("application/x-download");
    // response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcel.xls");
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Excel.xlsx");
    my_workbook.write(output);
    output.close();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is, your description is vague.

Comment: Sorry about my language issue, i tried provide more information and re-explain again my problem. Kindly advice. Thank You.

Comment: I remember something about Internet Explorer being annoying if you use the wrong content-type or content-disposition, not sure about the details though.

Comment: i tried to remove response.setContentType, but the problem still there. Is that possible google chrome browser blocked the prompt-out?

Comment: The content type in your code looks wrong. What happens if you set the correct content type for an Excel .xlsx file?

Comment: ya. I tried modify the content type, the prompt-out screen still not function.. am i did something wrong? Thanks.    Note: i was updated my modified code on the first post.

Comment: This is not a POI question. Your problem is related to a behaviour that is purely driven by the user preferences in the browser of a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an solution for my own question which is the Ajax is not allowed to download the file.

[Refer from buddy: Why threre is no way to download file using ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682556/why-threre-is-no-way-to-download-file-using-ajax-request)

The reason because i call ajax in my extjs file. haiz...

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to your problem.

with ajax call you can save file to disk. it remains to memory only you can have a workaround for this.

```
post2Url("./ExportToExceljQgrid.do?, 
        { 
            "getRowData":JSON.stringify($("#treegrid").jqGrid('getRowData')),
            "colNames" : JSON.stringify($("#treegrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','colNames')),
            "groupHeader" : JSON.stringify($("#treegrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "groupHeader").groupHeaders)
        }
        , 'post');

function post2Url(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; 
    var postForm = document.createElement("form");
    postForm.name = "exportForm";
    postForm.method = method;
    postForm.action = path;
    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
            postForm.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(postForm);
    postForm.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(postForm);
}
```

you get all the json data as parameters in request