# PDF download not working using ext js

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, pdf, extjs

I am new to `Extjs`. I am trying to download a pdf file coming from server by clicking on pdf link in `PDF`column of a grid table, but not able to download that file. Please help me to resolve this.

Please find my code snippet below.

### PDF Column

```
{
    header: "PDF",
    align: 'center',
    width: 35,
    renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
        if(record.get("extension") == "pdf") {
            metaData.style = 'text-decoration:underline;';
            metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + record.get("eventURI") + '"';
            return 'PDF';

        }
        else
            return '';

    }
}
```

### AJAX Call

```
if (colName == 'PDF'  && currentRow.get('extension')=="pdf") {
    if (!Ext.fly('fsfrmDummy')) {
        var frm = document.createElement('form');
        frm.id = 'fsfrmDummy';
        frm.name = 'fsfrmDummy';
        frm.className = 'x-hidden';
        document.body.appendChild(frm);
    }
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'edash/downloadDoc.action',
        params: {docUri: currentRow.get('eventURI')},
        success: function (response, config) {
        },
        failure: function (response, config) {
            appException('ERROR', response.message,
                    Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    Ext.Msg.OK);
        },
        form: Ext.fly('fsfrmDummy'),
        isUpload: true
    });
}
```

### Event URI

```
{
    header: "EVENT_URI",
    width: 95,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'eventURI',

    renderer: function (value, metaData,record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {


        if(record.get("extension") == "pdf") { 
            metaData.style = 'text-decoration:underline;';

        }
        return value;

    }

}
```

### Server side code

```
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, ? extends Object> downloadPDF(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam String docUri) {
    CheckOutDocumentResult out = null;
    try {
        out = eDashService.getDocument(docUri);
        String ext = out.getDocumentFileExtension();
        String fname = out.getDocumentFileName();
        if (ext != null && ext.toLowerCase().equals("pdf")) {
            response.setContentType("APPLICATION/pdf");
            String headerSetting = "attachment; filename=\"" + fname + "\";";
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
                    + fname + "\";");
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.getFileData());
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            int bytes;
            while ((bytes = bis.read()) != -1) {
                responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (out.getDocumentFileName().equals("null")) {
        return geteDashMapError(out.getErrorMessage());
    }else{
        return geteDashMapStatus("no errors");
    }
}
```

What was the wrong I did here???

Comment: Could you please better describe *not able to download*. Can you download when you access the url directly ?

Comment: In my app, we have a column named as `PDF`, in that column we have PDF links per row, means we can download the data in pdf format when we click on PDF link. But in my situation, when i am clicking on PDF link, the action is not getting performed...

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do an Ajax Request for downloading files.**

On click of your link do a standard submit requesting the file, I had trouble trying to do the same for downloading an Excel file.

**Fixed it doing a standard submit**

Here is a thread talking about downloading files through Ajax requests.

[Why threre is no way to download file using ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682556/why-threre-is-no-way-to-download-file-using-ajax-request)

Best regards.

Comment: But I am able to download excel file, but not PDF. I found out the problem where the issue was. The problem is while checkingout the document by invoking webservice. I am trying to resolve that.

Comment: I guess you are downloading your Excel file as an xml and then writting it to Excel?