# Download a file that needs authentication token

Tags: ajax, angularjs, spring-security

I am implementing an AngularJS app with a REST backend (using Spring Boot).

I can currently download a file like this:

```
<td><a href="/api/datasheets/{{datasheet.id}}/documents/{{document.id}}/download" download>Download</a></td>
```

Now, I am adding security (using Spring Security) to my application and this now no longer works. The authentication of the AJAX calls works by adding `x-auth-token` in the HTTP header for each request.

But a simple `href` does not have the `x-auth-token` in the header ofcourse. I tried using `$http.get()` on an `ng-click`, but [that cannot not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682556/why-threre-is-no-way-to-download-file-using-ajax-request).

Is there a simple alternative?

Comment: I'm facing a similiar problem with ember js and oauth. Did you find a best practise?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem while implementing file downloads in angular. In my case, I was not able to handle blob in safari. What I did was: create a handler which returns a download token valid for say 5 second. Only authenticated user can get this token. Once you have the token, call a different handler which returns the file after validating the token and this handler is publicly accessible. So you don't need to send authentication header while downloading file.

I used [itsdangerous library](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/) to implement timstamped token.