# PHPExcel file download using AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, download, phpexcel

I have a PHPExcel code which I use to export file, It works completely fine when i run it through normal static inputs but when tried with ajax calls the file is not getting downloaded.
the php code to generate code is as follows

```
include "dbconnect.php";
include 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
include 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
if (isset($_POST['sql'])) {
    $sql=mysql_query($_POST['sql']);
    echo $sql;
    if($sql === FALSE) {
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'A');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'B');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'C');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'D');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'E');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1', 'F');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G1', 'G');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H1', 'H');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I1', 'I');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J1', 'J');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K1', 'K');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L1', 'L');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M1', 'M');

    $n=2;

    while($sqlr= mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$n, $sqlr['a']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B'.$n, $sqlr['b']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.$n, $sqlr['c']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.$n, $sqlr['d']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E'.$n, $sqlr['e']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F'.$n, $sqlr['f']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('G'.$n, $sqlr['g']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$n, $sqlr['h']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$n, $sqlr['i']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J'.$n, $sqlr['j']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K'.$n, $sqlr['k']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('L'.$n, $sqlr['l']);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('M'.$n, $sqlr['m']);
        $n++;
    }
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('SORTED');

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    for($col = 'A'; $col !== 'Z'; $col++) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getColumnDimension($col)
            ->setAutoSize(true);

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:M1")->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('A1:M1')
            ->getFill()
            ->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)
            ->getStartColor()
            ->setARGB('75b847');
    }

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    ob_end_clean();
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="reports.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
else {
    echo "no luck";
}
?>
```

And the JS is as follows

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit2", function() {
    var sql=$("#sql").val();
    console.log(sql);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'exreports.php',
        data: {
            sql : sql
        },
        success: function () {
            window.open(this.url,'_blank' );
        }
    });

});
```

But this is not downloading the file, I dont want to refresh the page as user might perform some other operations, if there is any way to download in the same window it will be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel download using ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701981/phpexcel-download-using-ajax-call)

Comment: I tried that but its not working for me,no luck using that too @NochetImchen

Comment: Try using `window.location()` not `window.open`

Comment: @NochetImchen tried that too but its not redirecting and addition to that I am also posting some data, i guess its not entering into a success callback

Comment: write the code `window.location.href()` seperately not inside ajax. You cannot download files using ajax anyway. It is a security thing so browsers don't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27702111/8221063

add `target=_blank` in your ajax success function like below

```
success: function(){
  window.open('http://YOUR_URL','_blank' );
},
```

otherwise you can handle smartly to open your Excel download link in new tab with jQuery trigger function or etc.