# Detect finish of "php://output" with window.open

Tags: javascript, php

I use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for export mysql data in this way:

**Page 1:**

`button` trigger `window.open` to page with script for export

```
window.open('/export.php?data.., '_self');
```

**Page 2 (export.php):**

Whole system for export and `php://output`

```
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
$objWriter->save('php://output');            
exit;
```

Can I somehow understand if the export page has finished?
I need this for trigger a overlay.

**What i have tried?**

Looking in stackoverflow I tried this solution but it didn't work:

```
overlay.style.display = "block";
let myPopup =  window.open('/export.php?data.., '_self');
myPopup.addEventListener('load', () => {
   console.log('load'); //just for debug
   overlay.style.display = "none";
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give +1 to @Kinglish answer because `awaitLoad` function can help, in my case i used ajax instead with this method [Link answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36412422/12402732)

**What is it about?**

- Create an Ajax call with json type to export page and use `done` to catch `JSON`
  like:

  ```
  overlay.style.display = "block"; //active overlay
  $.ajax({
    url: "/export.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      data: data
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    var $a = $("<a>");
    $a.attr("href", data.file);
    $("body").append($a);
    $a.attr("download", "nameoffile.xls");
    $a[0].click();
    $a.remove();
    overlay.style.display = "none"; //deactive overlay
  });
  ```
- In PHP page catch `php://output` with `ob_get_contents` then return json like:

  ```
  $xlsData = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  $response = array(
    'op' => 'ok',
    'nomefile' => 'nameofile',
    'file' => "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,".base64_encode($xlsData)
  );
  die(json_encode($response));
  ```
- The last step is create, click and remove a fake link.

Answer (score 1):

This will execute an ajax request which will result in a download without refreshing the page with jQuery

```
<button id='download'>Download Spreadsheet</button>
<form method='get' action='/export.php?' id='hiddenForm'>
  <input type='hidden' name='foo' value='bar' />
  <input type='hidden' name='foo2' value='bar2' />
</form>


$(document).on('click', '#download', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#hiddenForm').submit();
});
```

Make sure your PHP outputs the correct content type

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

---

Another Option

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52462427/1772933), there isn't an api available to truly detect the loading of a javascript window object across all different browsers. This method uses a defer callback and `postMessage` approach to acommodate most modern browsers.

```
function defer (callback) {
    var channel = new MessageChannel();
    channel.port1.onmessage = function (e) {
        callback();
    };
    channel.port2.postMessage(null);
}

var awaitLoad = function (win, cb){
    var wasCalled = false;
    function unloadListener(){
        if (wasCalled)
            return;
        wasCalled = true;
        win.removeEventListener("unload", unloadListener);
        win.removeEventListener("pagehide", unloadListener);
        // Firefox keeps window event listeners for multiple page loads
        defer(function (){
            win.document.readyState;
            // IE sometimes throws security error if not accessed 2 times
            if (win.document.readyState === "loading")
                win.addEventListener("load", function loadListener(){
                    win.removeEventListener("load", loadListener);
                    cb();
                });
            else
                cb();
        });
    };
    win.addEventListener("unload", unloadListener);
    win.addEventListener("pagehide", unloadListener);
    // Safari does not support unload
}


w = window.open();
w.location.href="/export.php?data=foo";
awaitLoad(w, function (){
   console.log('got it')
});
```

Comment: That method only work if i manually close the window and don't use `_self`, do you know a method for close window after `$objWriter->save('php://output');` because i try to use `ob_clean();` and `echo "<script>window.close();</script>";`  for close it but nothing work.

Comment: Initially I was focused on just working with an open window and detection of load completion. Now I am asking myself why this method? Why not an async fetch or ajax request?

Comment: It was actually a method of having a loader in the meantime that I was tweaking things, and ajax request will allow do use `php://output` ?

Comment: I updated my answer with another option for ajax download from php://ouput without page reload

Comment: I try your method but when press the button all data after `/export.php?` it's deleted

Comment: ok, updated with a much simpler approach. define form fields in a hidden form and submit through jquery. PHP output headers also included, but you will need to customize those

Comment: With `php://output` doesn't exist a `$file` and how that can resolve the main problem? how i can detect the finish of script? because if you use form it's same as used `open window`.