# Unable to download a file using PHPexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using the following code to download a excel file

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
```

after this I add data to the Excel object and finally I call the code

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$exportFileName');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
die();
```

Here $exportFileName is the name of the .xlsx file But when I execute the code , the file does not  downloads but I can see the following junk characters in the console

[image: the code output]

Let me know How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to download a file through Ajax?

Comment: yes I am making an api call through ajax

Comment: You can't download files using Ajax, or at least not in an easy way. Open the download link in a new tab instead and it should work.

Comment: Thanks M.Eriksson. I found some information here:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701981/phpexcel-download-using-ajax-call