# Grails: Generate a Jasperreport with a Ajax-called controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, jasper-reports

I have an input field where I enter a value, the `millis` parameter, that is used as parameter to generate a Jasperreport. I´m using Ajax to call the controller that generates the report. The problem is that, although the report seems to be successfully generated, the download dialog is never shown.

Here´s part of my code:

```
/*THE BUTTON USED FOR MY GSP VIEW*/
<button id="imprimir" type="button">IMPRIMIR LOTES LIQUIDADOS</button>


/*JAVASCRIPT CODE TO CALL THE CONTROLLER*/
$("#imprimir").bind("click",imprimir);

function imprimir(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Liquidaciones/liquidacionDeComplejo/crearReporteGrupal2",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                millis:$("#millis").val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
            },
            error: function(request, status, error) {
            }
        });
    }

/*GRAILS CONTROLLER THAT GENERATES DE REPORT*/
def crearReporteGrupal2 = {
        Map reportParams = [:]
        def millis = params.millis.toBigDecimal()
        def realPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/reports/images/")
        reportParams.put("millis",millis)
        reportParams.put("realPath",realPath+"/")
        reportParams.put("SUBREPORT_DIR","${servletContext.getRealPath('/reports')}/")

        def reportDef = new JasperReportDef(name:'liquidacion_grupal_complejo.jasper',fileFormat:JasperExportFormat.PDF_FORMAT,parameters: reportParams)
        byte[] bytes
        bytes = jasperService.generateReport(reportDef).toByteArray()
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="liquidacion_grupal.pdf"')
        response.contentType = 'application/pdf'
        response.outputStream << bytes
        response.outputStream.flush()
        //I read somewhere that is necessary to return 'something' to initiate the download
        //but it didn't help
        //return null
        //render [:] as JSON
    }
```

Here the result from the server:
[image: server_response]

But when I copy this URL:`/Liquidaciones/liquidacionDeComplejo/crearReporteGrupal2?millis=1420757752558` from the Web Console and paste it in a new tab the download dialog appears.
[image: download_dialog]

Please help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot generate any reports/files from ajax. I will suggest you to make a form in you view and submit it with required parameters to the same controller and action. It will return the dialog box to save your report as mentioned by you.

Code:

```
function imprimir(){
            $('<form>', {
                "id": "imprimir",
                "html": '<input type="text" id="millis" name="millis" value="' + $("#millis").val() + '" />',
                "action": '/Liquidaciones/liquidacionDeComplejo/crearReporteGrupal2'
            }).appendTo(document.body).submit();
        }
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you, that worked! But I still have a doubt, why can't be generated reports/files from Ajax?

Comment: You can generate files using ajax but it has some pain while downloading file through ajax. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14683228/744553