# Why form can be used to download file but AJAX cannot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Given two codes, both trying to trigger server to give back of downloadable file using http header in response i.e. `"Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.ext`:

1. Using *form*, `$('<form></form>').attr('href', path) ... .submit().remove();`
2. Using *ajax*, `$.ajax(url, config);`

I would like to know why browsers handle that differently, since `form` and `ajax` are not quite different in term of sending request and receiving servers responses. I have search around, but nothing is convincing.

PS: I'm aware of CROS, but in this case **cross domain** is not an issue here.

Comment: Your constraints around what constitutes an improper answer are more clear than your actual question

Comment: Forms don't do downloads...where does that concept come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week, I now have a better understanding that is going on, and I want to share it with people who need.

Actually, it depends both on the server side for response and how the browsers will handle that response.

For example,

1. `form`, using `target` attribute which the default is `_self` to redirect user from link to link, and client side will implement how to handle response return from server.
2. `iframe`, similarly server will return a response and client side must know how to handle that response, it could redirect the user to another page by automatically refresh its iframe, or handle the response in `onload` event from its parent page.
3. Using `XMLHTTPRequest`, aka `AJAX`. Since AJAX is request-response type of thing, regardless of the response header, i.e. `Content-disposition: attachment; filename=fname.ext` will not work like expected, which is a pop-open a window and prompt user to download as file. Instead, AJAX will store the response in its `response` filed rather than treat it as a file. 
   (AJAX developed to provide no refresh page experience)
   Browser can be implemented differently to handle, but that will defeat the purpose of AJAX, thus browsers just store it in its memory.

So, how do we handle that chunk of memory and get it out as file? Introducing [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

After we get the response from server, we can construct a Blob file and invoke the browser to download, of course, [Blob is not all supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=blob) yet by the time of written May, 2015.
By the way, [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library does a good job to provide cross browser functionality.

Thus, without providing a direct download link with `href`, we can download
file using above methods. I personally will recommend to use AJAX, because of its seamless user experience.

Reference:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086435
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14683228
3. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of AJAX is to return the response to your SJ code.

That's exactly the opposite of downloading a file, which serves the response to the user.