# AngularJS Post request to Web service for downloading a file

Tags: ajax, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I need to send JSON to a web service using HTTP POST method in AngularJS to download a file.

AngularJS:-

```
$http
                .post(
                    'url',
                    'My Json data ')
                .success(function(response) {
                    console.log('file downloading');
                })
                .error(
                    function(response) {
                        console
                            .log('Error while downloading file');
                    });
```

Spring Controller:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void getfile(@RequestBody List<ABC> abc, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws JRException, IOException, SQLException {
//My code here 
        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/x-pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=ABC.pdf");
        final OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();  
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
```

I have to call this from angular using POST request. How to acheive so?

**EDIT**
I was able to meet the requirements by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit) thread.

Comment: be more detailed, where is exactly your problem?

Comment: See the explanation why you can't download file in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682556/why-threre-is-no-way-to-download-file-using-ajax-request SO thread.

Comment: @NikolayRusev I am unable to download the file in the browser as it is an ajax request. Requirement is sending POST request to server which will stream data in HTTP output stream which will result in downloading of file.

Comment: do it without ajax request

Comment: @NikolayRusev without ajax means creating form and hidden parameter kind of stuff?

Comment: why do you want to use post method?

Comment: @NikolayRusev because I want to send array of json to server for processing request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see [this](https://gist.github.com/DavidMah/3533415) very helpful function to download a file using POST request. Function is dependant on jQuery . the implementation creates a html form inline with hidden field and then submit it

Comment: Yes, I was able to do that by referring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit. Thanks for info Nikolay.