# Force to download file using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using image picker plugin to select an image then force it to download. I tried hard coding the PHP and it works as expected. Download pops-up and I managed to view the file. I'm not sure why it didnt work in AJAX. What am I missing?

```
    //get the image-source or URL
    function getImageSrc()
    {
        var req = $("div[class='thumbnail selected']").children('img');
            var imagessource = []; 
                $(req).each(function (datakey, datavalue) {
                                src =  $(datavalue).attr('src'); 
                                        imagessource.push(src);
                                              }); 
                      return(imagessource);
    }
```

Here's when I click the button

```
 $("#download_media").click(function() {
                    var file = getImageSrc();    

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '?page=downloadController&action=downloadMedia',
                        data: {'file_url': file},
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log("success");
                        }   
                    }); 
                });
```

My PHP FILE

```
 public function downloadMediaAction()
 {   
    //get the file_url
    $file = $this->getRequest()->('file_url');

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    readfile($file);
}
```

Comment: You want the browser to display the download window etc? Then just redirect to that link. AJAX is not meant for that.

Comment: when I try, window.location('ur'), it just display the page. it did not download.

Comment: Did you try searching before you posted this question? I came across plenty of answers addressing **your exact question** after spending only 15 seconds in [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?site=&source=hp&q=ajax+force+file+download&oq=ajax+force+file+download&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i22i30l2.142.4160.0.4325.27.17.1.0.0.1.623.2589.2-2j3j1j1.7.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.hp..20.7.2201.0.WdAWKKEFaK0): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502267/download-a-file-using-ajax

Comment: `content-disposition: attachment` should be all you need to tell the browser to ask the user what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then from your AJAX request, return the URL of the document to download like :

`{'url':'http://server:port/path/to/file.php?id=x'}`

and then using javascript

`document.location='http://server:port/path/to/file.php?id=x';`

in file.php call your method : `public function downloadMediaAction()`

and to make sure the browser will download it add this line to the `downloadMediaAction()` :

`header("Content-Type: application/force-download");`

Comment: He's using ajax to make the request, so no, adding a header **will not work**.

Comment: It is a bad idea to lie about content types.

Comment: It used to work for me in all major browsers

Comment: It still didnt work. What is the best solution here?

Comment: @asdasdas check out my new answer

Comment: I think sometimes you have to lie about the content ;)